# rbenv not changing ruby version

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I installed rbenv according to the github directions. I am running OSX but I have tried this on a Ubuntu 12.04 VM and got the same results. The following is what i get in my terminal when I try to change ruby versions:

```
rbenv versions
* 1.9.3-p0 (set by /Users/user/.rbenv/version)
1.9.3-p125

rbenv global
1.9.3-p0

rbenv rehash

ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [universal-darwin11.0]

which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why rbenv isn't switching the ruby version like it thinks it is? Also there is no .rbenv file in the local directory that would be causing the ruby version to default to 1.8.7

```
rbenv local
rbenv: no local version configured for this directory
```

Comment: Have you definitely put the init in your bashrc correctly?  What does your $PATH look like?

Comment: None of those commands change the Ruby version rbenv is using, but it appears it's not using your default Ruby.

Comment: @d11wtq was correct. it wasnt in my ~/.bash_profile correctly apparently.

Comment: make sure you follow ALL the installation **steps** for `rbenv`. See [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/master/README.md#homebrew-on-macos) or [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65460985/5175709)

Comment: If ruby was installed through brew, uninstall that first and then use rbenv.

Answer (score 848, accepted):

Check that PATH contains `$HOME/.rbenv/shims` and `$HOME/.rbenv/bin`

```
$ env | grep PATH
```

Also check that you have the following in your ~/.bash_profile if using bash or ~/.zshenv if using zsh

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

NOTE:
Make sure it's the last setting in your ~/.bash_profile . I ran into an issue where I installed a program that updated my .bash_profile and reset PATH.

Finally, make sure your `$HOME` folder doesn't have a `.ruby-version` file that you may have created by accident if you were to have done `$ rbenv local <ruby-version>` in your `$HOME` folder. Doing `$ rbenv global <ruby-version>` modifies the `$HOME/.rbenv/version` file, and the existence of a `.ruby-version` file in the `$HOME` folder would override the version set by `$HOME/.rbenv/version`.

From the docs:

> Choosing the Ruby Version
> When you execute a shim, rbenv determines which Ruby version to use by reading it from the following sources, in this order:

> The RBENV_VERSION environment variable, if specified. You can use the rbenv shell command to set this environment variable in your current shell session.

> The first .ruby-version file found by searching the directory of the script you are executing and each of its parent directories until reaching the root of your filesystem.

> The first .ruby-version file found by searching the current working directory and each of its parent directories until reaching the root of your filesystem. You can modify the .ruby-version file in the current working directory with the rbenv local command.

> The global ~/.rbenv/version file. You can modify this file using the rbenv global command. If the global version file is not present, rbenv assumes you want to use the "system" Ruby—i.e. whatever version would be run if rbenv weren't in your path.

Comment: On OSX, don't forget to log out of your OSX session and then log back in for the changes to your bash profile to take effect.

Comment: Or do `exec $SHELL -l` (lower L)

Comment: Where do I have to add the "$HOME/.rbenv/shims" and "$HOME/.rbenv/bin"?

Comment: I made like this:
`export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi`
Working pretty good :)
Also check for PATH init's after rbenv declaration.

Comment: For my case, I need to append these two lines into .bashrc (Bash in Ubuntu) and then I got correct ruby version. It does not work if append it into .bash_profile.

Comment: I had this because I was using zsh instead of bash. Solved it using  "echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.zshenv"

Comment: I just had to refer to the note, and move the imports below my homebrew path update in my .bash_profile.

Comment: When I typed `env | grep PATH` I got `PATH=/Users/username/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/bin` (How do I make it stop looking for RVM? I uninstalled RVM and installed rbenv instead.)

Comment: Please disregard my last comment. I figured it out. Even though `.bash_profile` had the correct **$PATH**, `.profile` did not. Fixed it.

Comment: Side note: personally, I switched to `asdf`. [Here's a post about how to do that.](https://wolfgangrittner.dev/switching-to-asdf-for-ruby/). The reason I chose it: it can also manage my node.js versions (and more)

Comment: followed steps                                                                                                           export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)" and then i get the latest ruby version which is 3.0.0 ( the one i installed) but when i log out of the terminal & log in.. it goes back to system ruby.. 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]..  what i am doing wrong ?? I installed ruby using rbenv.. followed https://wilsonmar.github.io/ruby-on-apple-mac-osx/#install-rbenv I am on mac os el capitan.

Comment: I need to append these two lines into ```.zshrc``` and then I got the correct ruby version.
OS: MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3(Apple M1)

Comment: instead of .bash_profile, .bash_rc worked for me. And the latest rbenv doesn't have a bin folder. You need to add shims folder.

Comment: % vim ```~/.zprofile``` (mac os use zsh with .zprofile instead of bash with .bash_profile)

Comment: Confirming that this did not work for me until I moved them to the END of ~/.zshrc

Comment: For a slightly more generic version, I believe chruby uses `~/.$(basename $SHELL)rc` to infer the correct file to append the above instructions into.

Comment: In my case, jetbrains was overriding the `RBENV_VERSION` environment variable. Make sure you don't forget to select the correct runtime in your IDE if it does 'smart' things like this ;-)

Answer (score 194):

I fixed this by adding the following to my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
#PATH for rbenv
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
```

This is what is documented at https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.

From what I can tell there **isn't** `~/.rbenv/bin` directory, which was mentioned in the post by @rodowi.

Comment: +1 for the link. +1 for the answer which does contradict a better voted answer.  Which raises a further question - and if anyone can chime in - how can `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH` work (as it was failing for me)?

Comment: There won't be a `~/.rbenv/bin/` if you installed via homebrew or linuxbrew. And you shouldn't have to set up the shims path yourself, as [`rbenv init` does this (and more) for you](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#how-rbenv-hooks-into-your-shell).

Comment: This fixed my problem.

Comment: This should be in the README

Comment: Worked for me after hours of trying other stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @onmyway133 it is in the readme. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65460985/5175709)

Answer (score 96):

This may be an old question, but Google led me here and, for posterity sake, thought I'd share.

My problem persisted after many of the recommended solutions above. Like the OP, I installed rbenv and then a ruby version, but my laptop defaulted to system. What I had overlooked was that when I ran:

```
[~/.rbenv] $ rbenv versions
* system (set by /Users/alphadogg/.rbenv/version)
  2.0.0-p247
```

IOW, it was still defaulting to system. A quick

```
[~/.rbenv] $ rbenv local 2.0.0-p247
```

switched it to the new version.

Comment: Yes - funny how rbenv install guides don't mention running the local command at all. Lots of blogs remind you to run rbenv global but not local. Great answer.

Comment: Same problem. Same solution. (May have to look at submitting a PR to advise when global Ruby version is overruled by a ~/.ruby-version...)

Comment: I had to get rid of system by removing with YUM in Centos 7, only after that I could see the correct version selected in rbenv

Comment: I'm shocked I had to dig this far for an answer, this is the correct one for me.

Comment: I found that the rbenv versions command said that 2.3.1 was set in .ruby-versions by rvm perhaps.  I had stopped using rvm awhile ago and changed to rbenv.  Deleted .ruby-versions and ran rbenv versions again and it had the latest selected by rbenv ( be sure you have the eval statement above in .bash_profile!).  Now, all works as before.  Thanks for helping me get this solved.

Answer (score 85):

First step is to find out which ruby is being called:

```
$ which ruby
```

Your system says:

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

This is NOT the shim used by rbenv, which (on MacOS) should look like:

```
/Users/<username>/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

The shim is actually a script that acts like a redirect to the version of ruby you set.

I recommend that for trouble shooting you unset the project specific "local" version, and the shell specific "shell" version and just test using the "global" version setting which is determined in a plain text file in ~/.rbenv/version which will just be the version number "1.9.3" in your case.

```
$ rbenv global 1.9.3
$ rbenv local --unset
$ rbenv shell --unset
```

You can do `ls -laG` in the root of your project folder (not the home folder) to make sure there is no longer a ".ruby-version" file there.

You can use `rbenv versions` to identify which version rbenv is set to use (and the location and name of the file that is setting that):

```
$ rbenv versions
```

NONE OF THAT MATTERS until you set the path correctly.

Use this to make sure your *MacOS will obey you:

```
$ rbenv init -
```

Followed by:

```
$ which ruby
```

To make sure it looks like:

```
/Users/<username>/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

Then run this to add the line to your profile so it runs each time you open a new terminal window:

```
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

There are other ways to modify the path, feel free to substitute any of them instead of running the rbenv init.

NOTE: reinstall Rails with:

```
$ gem install rails
```

If you were trying to run Ruby on Rails, then you need to have this all working first, then install the rails gem again.  A previous install of Rails will use a hard coded path to the wrong ruby and several other things will be in the wrong place, so just install the gem again.

P. S. If your MacOS won't obey you (*mentioned above) then you may have to find another way to modify your path, but that's unlikely to be a problem because "Macs just work" ;)

Comment: Ah mate, finally! Tried about 25 different solutions before I found this one, thank you

Comment: Well explained solution. Thank you.

Comment: this response is the most helpful (and complete) one.  One small variant:  `if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi >> ~/.bash_profile`  followed by `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Don't know why, but running `$ rbenv local --unset; rbenv shell --unset` and setting the global version worked for me. Even after restoring the `.ruby-version` file with the same version number, rbenv started working as expected.

Answer (score 71):

I had this issue when setting up Ruby using rbenv on **MacBook Pro Catalina OS** and **MacBook Pro Big Sur**.

Here's how I fixed:

First run the command below to initialize rbenv:

```
rbenv init
```

This will give you some instruction on what to do. Basically you will have to open the `~/.zshrc` file and add this to the file `eval "$(rbenv init -)"`. You can accomplish this by running the command below:

```
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Next, run the command below to set your Ruby version:

```
rbenv local <your-desired-ruby-version>
```

In my case, my desired Ruby version was 3.0.1, so it was:

```
rbenv local 3.0.1
```

When you are done, quit your terminal using **Command + Q**, and then open a new terminal, this time when you run the command:

```
ruby -v 
rbenv versions
```

You will see that your desired Ruby version has already been set up for you.

Comment: You are a . Worked on macOS Monterey.

Comment: @PHPNoob The OP mentions that AFAICS. Right near the bottom, it says "quit your terminal using Command + Q, and then open a new terminal." Unless I'm missing something, that's specific directions on how to restart the terminal.

Comment: Worked on macOS Venutra 

Comment: Thanks  works on Ventura too

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked on Ventura M1 Mac too

Answer (score 46):

In my case changing the `~/.zshenv` did not work. I had to make the changes inside `~/.zshrc`.

I just added:

```
# Include rbenv for ZSH
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

at the top of `~/.zshrc`, restarted the shell and logged out.

Check if it worked:

```
➜  ~ rbenv install 2.4.0
➜  ~ rbenv global 2.4.0
➜  ~ rbenv global
2.4.0
➜  ~ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

Comment: This perfectly works. I added that into .bash_profile not /zshenv.

Comment: Probably it will be necessary to run source ~/.zshrc, but it worked for me . Thanks you.

Comment: Works for me, but I don't understand what is the difference. `.zshenv` was also executed (checked it with `echo` inside. Oh, and not with `bin`, but with `shims` in a `PATH`.

Comment: After trying many suggestions, finally this one works for me. Probably this needs to be added to the official document.

Answer (score 38):

### Update 2023 (Macbook Ventura+)

Even if you have `rbenv` installed, your computer could still serve the default ruby version. To fix this, just run the following:

```bash
rbenv init
```

This might give an output like this:

```bash
# Load rbenv automatically by appending
# the following to ~/.zshrc:

eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
```

Just open your `.zshrc` file:

```bash
sudo nano ~/.zshrc
```

(Or you can also open this file with any other text editor)

Add this line:

```bash
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
```

Save the file (if used sudo nano, you can do so like this:)
`CTRL + X` then `Y` then `Enter` (For Mac)

Now, refresh your `.zshrc` profile like this:

```bash
source ~/.zshrc
```

Now type `ruby --version`, this must give you the ruby version that was provided by `rbenv`.

Comment: it was CONTROL X instead of CMD X for me.

Comment: Indeed, it was `CTRL + X` for me as well. Updating the answer!

Answer (score 32):

Run this command

Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal

```
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

this will solve your problem [Reference](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite)

Comment: I spent hours to fix this. Finally your solution helped. Thanks!!

Comment: I also tried all the answers above, none worked for me except this one. Thanks

Comment: thhhhhhhhhhhhhanks

Answer (score 31):

I just found this same problem. What I did was uninstall rbenv (via homebrew) and reinstall it. I also added

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

into ~/.bash_profile when I reinstalled rbenv. Works perfectly now.

Comment: Note for others that came to the same issue as me: For some reasons, which rbenv was working prior so this line was never executed. I fixed it using directly eval "$(rbenv init -)".

Comment: Nice little eval statement for this use case!

Answer (score 10):

If you are using **bash**, go to

```
~/.bash_profile
```

and add the following line (if it's not already there)

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

If you are using Zsh, go to

```
~/.zshrc
```

and add the same line of code, at the end of the .zshrc file.

Then simply restart your terminal and it should be fine now.

Comment: People on Mac os Catalina, should follow the zsh instruction

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, but caused by Homebrew:

```
[~]$ rbenv version
2.3.0 (set by /Users/user/.rbenv/version)
[~]$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-darwin16]
[~]$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

Somehow I had installed Ruby via Homebrew too, and the Homebrew path was ahead of the rbenv path in my `$PATH`. Running `brew uninstall ruby` fixed it for me.

Comment: If ruby was installed through brew, it must be uninstalled to use rbenv properly

Answer (score 8):

I tried every solution, but nothing worked for me. Even I was including the path in the `.zshrc` file.

In my case, I'm using `MacBook Pro M2` with macOS `Ventura 13.2`. And I'm using `React Native 0.71.2`, which needed Ruby `2.7.6` version.

I simply placed the following code in the `.zprofile` instead of `.zshrc`, and it worked:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
```

Comment: I was only missing the second line. Once added, closed and reopened the terminal and it worked fine

Comment: both of these lines are mandatory. using only single won't work

Answer (score 7):

`rbenv help shell`

"Sets a shell-specific Ruby version by setting the 'RBENV_VERSION' environment variable in your shell. This version overrides localapplication-specific versions and the global version. should be a string matching a Ruby version known to rbenv.The special version string 'system' will use your default system Ruby. Run rbenv versions' for a list of available Ruby versions."

Provided rbenv was installed correctly, ruby -v will correspond to

`rbenv shell 1.9.3-p125`

Comment: 'rbenv shell x.y.z' is what worked for me. The 'rbenv local x.y.z' described in the higher ranked answer above did not work on OS X.

Answer (score 6):

run:

```
rbenv init
```

After I ran that, when i set my local rbenv version:

```
rbenv local 2.4.0
```

then my `ruby -v` and my `rbenv local` versions coincided.

Note: You might also want to exit the directory you're in and then go back into it, i've noticed that was necessary for me in order to get things to work.

Answer (score 5):

As for me the easiest way to use `rbenv` along with `zsh` is adding `rbenv` to plugins section in `.zshrc` config. In my case it looks similar to:

```
# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git bower rails ruby rbenv gulp npm node nvm sublime)
```

After that there're no problems when installing, switching, using ruby versions with help of `rbenv`.

Mind to restart your terminal session after made changes.

Comment: Only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 5):

for fish shell user

```
set --universal fish_user_paths $fish_user_paths ~/.rbenv/shims/
```

Comment: It worked, how did you come about this solution?

Comment: it works thank you, same question how did you comes with this ?????

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember anymore lol
That was 2017 answer and I wonder why this still works though
focused on mobile development now so i never use this stuff anymore.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer suggests to add the following:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

This will not work on Mac OSX, which the OP references. In fact, if you install rbenv via `brew install rbenv`, which is really the only installation method in Mac OSX, since `curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-installer | bash` will FAIL in OSX, then the rbenv executable will be installed in:

```
$ which rbenv
/usr/local/bin/rbenv
```

However, even in OSX, the rbenv root will remain in the $HOME directory:

```
~ viggy$ rbenv root
/Users/viggy/.rbenv
```

What does this mean? It means when you install rubies, they will install in the given home directory under .rbenv:

```
$ rbenv install 2.6.0
$ ls ~/.rbenv/versions
2.6.0
```

Now the brew installation did some work that you would have to perform manually in Linux. For example, in Linux, you would have to install ruby-build manually as a plugin:

```
$ mkdir -p "$(rvbenv root)/plugins"
$ git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git "(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build
```

This is already done with the homebrew installation. There is one important step that must be done in the homebrew installation, as in the Linux installation. You must add the rbenv shims to your path. In order to do that, when your shell starts, you have to evaluate the following command (which will in turn add the rbenv shims to the beginning of your $PATH):

```
$ vim ~/.bash_profile
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now when you run `echo $PATH`, you will see the rbenv shims:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/viggy/.rbenv/shims:
```

Now check your ruby version and it will reflect the rbenv ruby installed:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.6.0p0
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding the following to `.bashrc` works for me -

`export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"`

Comment: this is exactly what the accepted answer of 2020 says .

Answer (score 3):

I came to the same problem.
Fixed this by run the `rbenv global` command with `sudo`.
I think it was something permission problem.

update:
I finally found the solution.
There was one same file "version" on my mac,  which is under `/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.3.0/`.
I think it was created by mistake occasionally. you should remove it.

Answer (score 3):

When I had these symptoms, the problem turned out to be that install had failed halfway through for the new Ruby version I was trying to switch to, without me noticing. The fix was to delete & reinstall it.

(This meant that even though ruby 1.9.3 showed up in the rbenv list of available versions, it didn't have an executable on the path where rbenv assumed it would. Since rbenv tries to change your ruby version just by prepending a location to your path, if there's nothing actually in the location it prepends, your OS will happily continue searching your default path and find your system version, in my case like the question's 1.8.7.)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the last line of your `.bash_profile` is:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me right after I reinstalled `rbenv`. Apparently I had a `.ruby-version` file in my home directory, specifying a version that no longer existed. Once I deleted the file, everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

HOW TO INSTALL RUBY RBENV
Just like many other tools, we turn to the popular Homebrew macOS package manager. Run the following command in your terminal:

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build
```

Once everything is installed, we need to instruct rbenv to setup our shell, so we’re using the Ruby runtime version that we’ve customly installed with rbenv whenever we open a new terminal window to type commands in the prompt (as opposed to the preinstalled Ruby 2.6.8 version on the macOS).

To setup rbenv with your shell run the following command:

```
rbenv init
```

Follow the on-screen printed instructions if any extra configuration is required on your part. You might be asked to paste a command in your shell’s configuration. If you’re on a macOS and haven’t changed from the default Z Shell (ZSH), then you’ll want to make sure you add the following line of code to the top of your ~/.zshrc file:

```
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
```

The rbenv install process is now complete. You might want to run some diagnostic checks to ensure that everything is set up correctly. If so, you can run the rbenv-doctor tool that the rbenv GitHub project provides:

Open a new terminal window so that you have the new rbenv environment loaded
Run the command:
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/main/bin/rbenv-doctor | zsh
Warning: This command shouldn’t be taken lightly, as you are piping commands into your development environment’s shell that originate from a public and open source GitHub repository. It is possible that a malicious actor had tampered with the source code, so you are highly encouraged to review the code properly before you run this command.

How do you use rbenv to install a new Ruby version?
Congrats on building your own Ruby virtual environment! Now that you have a functional rbenv setup we can use it to completely manage your Ruby versions.

To begin, you want to list which Ruby versions are available for installation so you can choose the latest Ruby release, or perhaps a specific version that you’re looking for. To use rbenv to list all Ruby versions, run the following command:

```
rbenv install -l
```

The output of which was:

2.6.10
2.7.6
3.0.4
3.1.2
jruby-9.3.6.0
mruby-3.1.0
picoruby-3.0.0
rbx-5.0
truffleruby-22.1.0
truffleruby+graalvm-22.1.0

Only latest stable releases for each Ruby implementation are shown.
Use 'rbenv install --list-all / -L' to show all local versions.
You can then proceed to installing one of these Ruby versions. Let’s use rbenv to install a Ruby version of 3.1.2:

```
rbenv install 3.1.2
```

The command will then start fetching the relevant source code files to extract, compile, and then install the Ruby 3.1.2 runtime version available to your shell.

When you’ve finished installing it, you should set it to be the chosen version anytime your shell starts. To do that, you need to run:

```
rbenv global 3.1.2
```

Finally, you can verify that this is working as expected by running the ruby --version in your shell, which should output a similar result:

Answer (score 1):

There a lot of of misleading answers that work. I thought it was worth mentioning the steps from the [`rbenv` README](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-macos).

1. `$ brew install rbenv`
2. `$ rbenv init` **and follow** the instructions it gives you. This is what I got:

```
~ $ rbenv init
# Load rbenv automatically by appending
# the following to ~/.bash_profile:

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

I updated my `~/.bash_profile`...

3. Close terminal and open it again
4. Verify it's working correctly by running:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash
```

5. Now just install the version you want by doing: `rbenv install <version>`

Answer (score 1):

Linux / Ubuntu Users
Step 1:

```
$ rbenv versions
  system
  2.6.0
* 2.7.0 (set by /home/User/Documents/sample-app/.ruby-version) #Yours will be different
  2.7.2
```

Step 2:

```
$ nano /home/User/Documents/sample-app/.ruby-version
```

Step 3:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, `rbenv` version did not set the `.rbenv` file.

Check with: `ls -ltra` --> to see that a `rbenv` was written.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#readme)? chruby does not rely on shims, instead it only modifies `PATH`, `GEM_HOME`, `GEM_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to delete rvm before installing rbenv. I deleted rvm and re-installed rbenv, but system still wasn't using the version of Ruby being designated as global by rbenv. I tried shutting Terminal, but it only worked once I restarted the whole machine.

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers here give good advice for various situations, but there is an easier way.

The rbenv docs point us to the rbenv-doctor diagnostic tool that will quickly verify all these potential pitfalls on your system:

```
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash
```

When all is well, you'll see this:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash                                     <aws:hd-pmp-developer>
Checking for `rbenv' in PATH: /usr/local/bin/rbenv
Checking for rbenv shims in PATH: OK
Checking `rbenv install' support: /usr/local/bin/rbenv-install (ruby-build 20201005)
Counting installed Ruby versions: 1 versions
Checking RubyGems settings: OK
Auditing installed plugins: OK
```

Now, if we break one of those expectations (e.g. remove rbenv-install), the tool will point us directly to the problem, with a link to how to fix it:

```
$ mv /usr/local/bin/rbenv-install rbenv-install-GONE
                                                                      
$ curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash                                     
Checking for `rbenv' in PATH: /usr/local/bin/rbenv
Checking for rbenv shims in PATH: OK

===> Checking `rbenv install' support: not found <===
  Unless you plan to add Ruby versions manually, you should install ruby-build.
  Please refer to https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#installation

Counting installed Ruby versions: 1 versions
Checking RubyGems settings: OK
Auditing installed plugins: OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding eval "$(rbenv init -)" to the .bash_profile on my mac resolved this issue.
rbenv local 
ruby -v gave the set

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Apparently, it worked for me when I used the **Rosetta** terminal

You can try doing the same thing using **Rosetta** terminal

by going into

Finder > Utilities > Terminal > Get Info

Answer (score -4):

I will suggest do not use rbenv has couple of issues.

1. it does not come with bundle version once you install ruby
2. most of time create bundler version pickup issue while running bundle install

To cut down this much effort,I would suggest to use rvm, make life easier.
follow this link to install rvm https://nrogap.medium.com/install-rvm-in-macos-step-by-step-d3b3c236953b

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem if their organization is using rbenv or if they must use rbenv for some other reason. It's unrelated to the question