# Trying to git pull with error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Tags: git, github, pull

Help me please, I am trying to run this in my terminal:

```
asgard@asgard-A7N8X2-0:~/CollegePortal$ git pull
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

Then I try this one

```
asgard@asgard-A7N8X2-0:~/CollegePortal$ sudo git pull
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Help me, I don't understand this problem.

Comment: Have you added your public key to github account?

Comment: Do you have write permission for the local directory & files where you try to do pull? Also, probably `sudo` doesn't help here at all since it needs access to you ssh keys (not root's).

Comment: I had this problem and solved it by giving my user Modify & Full Access permissions to that folder (Windows)

Comment: I ran cmd  on Windows as Administrator and this fixed it for me. Thank you to Benjamin Bannier for showing that it's a permission problem.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

It seems like the first one isn't working because your user doesn't have the permissions for changing that directory, and the second because your root user doesn't have the right SSH keys for accessing that git repository.

Depending on what you're trying to do, it might be better to clone the repository to a different directory, or maybe `chown` the current directory to have full access for your user

Comment: This often happens when you accidently forget you've run `sudo su` and your acting as root in a repo.  A simple `sudo chown -R <username> .` in that directory works magic!

Comment: Just give Read and Write permission to your current directory. thats it! 'sudo chmod 777 amt/ -R'

Comment: Some thing similar, My directory location was in c: (windows) and I needed admin rights. Moved to another location and it worked fine.

Answer (score 196):

Check if you have enough permissions on the `.git/` directory. You should have write permissions. You can set them with the following command.

Go to your project folder:

```
chown -R youruser:yourgroup .git/
```

Comment: It should be `chown -R youruser .git/`

Answer (score 58):

If you want to give the permission to the group,

```
sudo chmod g+w .git -R
```

worked best for me.

For MacOS

```
sudo chmod -R g+w .git
```

Answer (score 37):

Try like this way,

**Step 1:** First check who you are? it will return current user name e.g **ubuntu**

```
$ whoami
```

**Step 2:** Then set permission to your current user, in that case, **ubuntu** by

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu .git/
```

Answer (score 35):

In my case work fine after it:

```
rm -f .git/FETCH_HEAD

git branch -u
```

Answer (score 34):

This is a UNIX permission problem. Do not use `sudo` for cloning the repository. You don't have the same ssh keys as root and you shouldn't work as root anyway. Try `ls -la` to find the permissions on the files and use `chmod` (or `sudo chown`) to fix them. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 27):

The answer to this issue make sure .git/FETCH_HEAD has write privileges and you will be all set.

I had this issue on Windows and it was resolved by giving write permissions.

In unix one can run `chmod a+rw .git/FETCH_HEAD` from the project repository after which it should work.

Comment: does't work with `.git/FETCH_HEAD` alone if permission issue is on `.git`.

Answer (score 19):

This will resolve all permissions in folder

```sh
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ./
```

Comment: This will always work but it can have the effect of trampling access for other users. Be aware that previous answers were taking group access into account where this answer does not.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I only had read access to the .git/FETCH_HEAD file.  I had to do "sudo chmod g+w .git/FETCH_HEAD" in order to be able to do a pull request.

Comment: does't work with `.git/FETCH_HEAD` alone if permission issue is on `.git`.

Comment: I had to allow write access to the git folder for group `sudo chmod g+w .git/FETCH_HEAD`

Comment: `sudo chmod g+w .git/FETCH_HEAD`, perfect solution.

Answer (score 12):

I was having the first issue (FETCH_HEAD permission denied) on Windows.

I fixed it by running Git Bash as an administrator (right click, run as administrator).

Answer (score 11):

If you haven't added yourself to the group that owns `.git/`, then you should.

```
sudo usermod -a -G $(stat -c '%G' .git) $USER
sudo chmod g+u .git -R
sudo chmod g+u .gitignore
su - $USER
```

What this does:

1. finds out which group owns `.git/` and adds your user to that group.
2. makes sure group members have the same permissions as the owner for `.git/`.
3. repeats this for `.gitignore`, which you'll probably need
4. logs you out and back in to refresh your group membership file permissions

If you just recently did something like this (added yourself to the group that owns `.git/`), then you need to log out and back in before you'll be able to write to `.git/FETCH_HEAD` during your `git pull`.

Answer (score 11):

Set permission to your current user by running the command

`$ sudo chown -R <username> .git/`

Answer (score 7):

Running Windows 7, when I had this issue it was because I had hidden the .git folder. The permissions were fine, it was just hidden. Showing the folder resolved it.

Answer (score 6):

Simply go to your **root folder** and run this command to add read/write permissions for all users:

```
chmod a+rw .git/FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 5):

`sudo chmod -R 777 .git` or if you want to add rw permissions for only yourself, you can use `sudo chmod -R +rw .git`

Answer (score 4):

**Error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied**

This work for me:

1. By default .git folder is hidden.
2. Unhide .git folder and its child folders and file and try to pull request.

Answer (score 4):

Use this command, its worked for me.

> sudo chown -R $USER: .

Reference: https://techoverflow.net/2019/05/07/how-to-fix-git-error-cannot-open-git-fetch_head-permission-denied/

Answer (score 3):

### This worked for me:

1. Right click .git folder
2. click get info
3. set permission to your user
4. click the Cog icon and click apply to enclosed items

**No more permission denied errors in git.**

Answer (score 3):

This issue arises when you don't give sufficient permissions to .git folder.
To solve this problem-

1. First navigate to your working directory.
2. Enter this command-

   > sudo chmod a+rw .git -R

Hope it helps..!!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the owner and group of `.git` directory with (first go to parent directory of .git) `ll .git` , look at the group and owner of the directory,
add your user to group of of the owner with `sudo usermod -a -G yourusername  groupsofonwner`, then logout => login and everything getting work.

So in summeries

1. go to parent directory of git

   ```
   $cd your path
   ```
2. find group owner of the `.git` direcotry

   ```
   $ll .git
   ```
3. add your user to that group

   ```
   $usermod -a -G yourusername ownergroupofgit
   ```
4. Logout and login to system to this change take effect.
5. Enjoy it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Got that issue when .git folder is hidden and all files in it is hidden too.
Make only .git folder hidden without recursive files update and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Reasons of this error could be multiples but in my case i updated branch with root then when i tried to update it with normal user it gives me error .

try both solutions one should work for you

```
1- sudo chmod g+w .git -R
```

if it doesn't work please try next solution hope it will solve your problem

```
2 - rm -f .git/FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the FETCH_HEAD in the .git file will solve the problem.

Comment: That's already mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29206450/2745495

Answer (score 1):

I had this message when using git extensions for windows. My fix was to simply close git extensions then open again as administrator

Answer (score 1):

In my case,

```bash
sudo chmod ug+wx .git -R
```

this command works.

This is what the parts of the command do:

- `sudo` = as an admin
- `chmod` = change permissions
- `ug` = for a user and group
- `+wx` = add write and execute permissions
- `.git` = the folder/file it applies to
- `-R` for recursive (all subfolders/files)

Comment: `sudo` = as an admin, `chmod` = change permissions, `ug` = user and group, `+wx` = add write and execute permissions, `.git` = the folder/file you're applying it to, `-R` for recursive (all subfolders/files)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error but in my case, the problem was the result of having rebuilt Apache after an upgrade to the PHP version.  Long story short, I forgot to install the Apache module 'suexec'.

It had nothing to do with group or ownership.  That only took me two days to figure out, someone shoot me...

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a dual-boot system (Windows 10 and Linux) with project folder on NTFS disk. It turned out that on another update Windows 10 enabled by itself "fast startup" in its settings. 
After I've unchecked it in the Windows - the "error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied" in Linux was gone.

Answer (score 1):

for MacOS user (if High Sierra or higher version) use this:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

Answer (score 1):

Many Answers here, many suggesting doing a chown.
For me was much easier to change user to the user owning the folder (in my case tomcat) as the owner was allowed to write:
`sudo su tomcat`
and than do a
`git pull`
no need to change permissions. I prefere this because I do not have to remember to change permission back after I am done.

To find the user owning the folder do a `ls -la`

Note: Do not give non-sudo write access to folders that are served!

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Windows 10 and I had the same issue. Here are 2 methods I tried.

1. I deleted the file (.git/FETCH_HEAD) and ran the command. It resolved the issue.

   OR
2. Usually .git folder will be hidden in the windows machine. In my laptop all the folders and files inside .git was also hidden. That's the reason I faced permission denied issue. After unhiding the files and folders, issue got resolved.

Thanks

-- Uday

Answer (score 0):

I got this because I had more than 1 user account on my box.  I was logged in as user A and was in a directory for user B.  User A didn't have permission to user B's stuff.  Once I realized I wasn't where I thought I was in the file system, this error made sense.

Answer (score 0):

if you find the same problem in windows server, then you need to run the command line with enough permission, such as administrator permission.

Answer (score 0):

When I was doing `bundle install` I got:

```
Following files may not be writable, so sudo is needed:
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/bin
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/build_info
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/bundler
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/cache
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/doc
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/specifications
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

I had followed the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12150580/5175709) and updated my `bash_profile` to add a `rbenv` shim.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

But for some unknown reason I had them commented out. Once I uncommented I was able to run `bundle install` successfully.

Answer (score -1):

**In my case work that:** I just wrote `sudo` before the command :

```
sudo npm run deploy
```

Answer (score -3):

My problem was with the Ubuntu command line.

I managed to solve it, after logging in as root.

```
sudo su
git pull
```