# Jenkins can't update the mirror git repo

Tags: git, ubuntu, jenkins, redmine, ubuntu-14.04

I am running a small ubuntu 14.04 where I have installed jenkins and redmine. For redmine I have added a git mirror in

> /var/lib/redmine/repos/repo.git

Every time jenkins successfully builds I want it to update the mirror as well so that redmine stays up to date. Well here is my problem. Somehow I can't seem to give jenkins the proper authority to execute the command 'git update remote' it keeps giving me a

> remote: error: cannot open FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

the rights on redmine/repos/* is root:root and I have tried to change this to jenkins:jenkins gitolite:gitolite but nothing seems to help. What can I do to let jenkins execute the command?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195814/trying-to-git-pull-with-error-cannot-open-git-fetch-head-permission-denied

Comment: tried to give FETCH_HEAD write permission and even 775 but it doesn't help..

Comment: Did you clone the repository here `/var/lib/redmine/repos/` as root user?

Comment: @Victor I did it with the sudo command because it wouldn't let me otherwise.. it gives a permission denied.