# git cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD

Tags: git, github, permissions, centos

I have CentOs. I make git and made owner's  .git folders  group "gitdevelopers". In group "gitdevelopers" add User1 and User2.  Now i make git-push and git-pull change from user1 and user2. But  users in your computers not work with error:

git.exe pull -v --no-rebase --progress "origin"
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Why?

p.s.:And i can connect to server by x-shell with login-password user1 and user2.

few hours later::
I think problem in not right login-password, which git remember.

p.p.s: where git save login-password pairs? I use ssh-protocol.

p.p.p.s.:OK. I have server CentOs with git. On server is two users.  And I use TortoiseGit for windows. I configure this so : in each connect system asked login and password for connect to server. And now I wanted know : 1. where is saved this login-password  2. i can  permanently saved this pair?

Comment: Did you try `git config core.sharedRepository true` (on the server, in the .git repos) + chmod as in http://serverfault.com/a/27040/783?

Comment: What protocol are you using when contacting the remote? https? ssh?

Comment: ssh means there is no login/password, only public and private keys stored in `~/.ssh/`(`id_rsa.pub`, `id_rsa`)

Comment: As long as you keep using "login" and "password", your ssh url won't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to git pull with error: cannot open .git/FETCH\_HEAD: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195814/trying-to-git-pull-with-error-cannot-open-git-fetch-head-permission-denied)

Answer (score 64):

This worked with me

```sh
sudo chown -R $(whoami) .git/
```

Comment: It worked well. Can you please explain the logic behind it ?

Comment: sudo chown=change ownership of directory,
 -R=make it recursive, meaning of all sub folders and files inside that directory,
 $(whoami)=get current logged in user,
 .git/=is the folder where info about git repository is stored, 
Hence this command will change the ownership of file to current user, so this user can perform commands like "git pull" etc.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using ubuntu, use sudo key word before.

```
sudo git pull
```

if you are using windows, use administrator mode

Answer (score 2):

you can check for the permissions on the file,

> ls -l /usr/local/Library/Taps/linode/cli/.git/FETCH_HEAD

and

> ls -l /usr/local/.git/FETCH_HEAD

Answer (score 0):

Generating a new SSH key pair

```
ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@domain.com"
```

Adding an SSH key to your GitLab account

```
Copy your public SSH key to the clipboard and paste it into your user account >  SSH Keys
```

For Authentication you need to set configuration in ~/.ssh/config as content bellow;

```
Host domain.com

Hostname domain.com

User git

Port 30001

Preferredauthentications publickey

RequestTTY no

IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

**You can use commands as;** In these command mentioned common variables, replace the related values of those.

**Create a new repository**

```
git clone ssh://git@domain.com:port-number/user-name/project-name.git

cd project-name

touch README.md

git add README.md

git commit -m "add README"

git push -u origin master
```

**Push an existing folder**

```
cd existing_folder

git init

git remote add origin ssh://git@domain.com:port-number/user-name/project-name.git

git add .

git commit -m "Initial commit"

git push -u origin master
```

**Push an existing Git repository**

```
cd existing_repo

git remote rename origin old-origin

git remote add origin ssh://git@domain.com:port-number/user-name/project-name.git

git push -u origin --all

git push -u origin --tags
```

**To clone repository:**

git clone https://git@domain.com:port-number/user-name/project-name.git

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
sudo chown -R $ USER: name_repo
```

note:
in my case I had cloned the repository with the root user and then I started using another user

Answer (score 0):

Delete the existing solution and doing a git clone solved the issue for me