# git pull not working when executed by apache but works on CLI

Tags: php, git, apache, bitbucket

I prepared a PHP script that runs

```
shell_exec("git pull");
```

it was supposed to be a webhook for git repo run everytime there are changes pushed to the remote. After execution nothing happens, I get an empty response.

I changed the directories owner to "apache" (repo was cloned as "apache"). I've generated a key and uploaded it to bitbucket. It seems to work correctly, when I run

```
# sudo -u apache git pull
```

it works perfectly. Doesn't prompt with anything.

when I run

```
shell_exec("whoami");
```

I get "apache".

Is it possible that php is blocking git pull? When I run other git commands (like git status), I get the response.

**UPDATE**

when I do

```
shell_exec("git pull 2>&1");
```

it says

```
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

I'm confused. I'm sure .git dirs and subdirs owner is apache and it has right priviliges to go...

**UPDATE #2**

I run

```
shell_exec("git --work-tree=/path/to/repo --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git pull 2>&1");
```

and it still says

```
error: cannot open /path/to/repo/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

no way! /path/to/repo/.git/FETCH_HEAD is readable by everyone!

I'm well confused.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195814/trying-to-git-pull-with-error-cannot-open-git-fetch-head-permission-denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

After spending many, many hours on trying to solve this problem, I found the answer.

SELinux was the problem. One simple command solved it

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

all working now!

Comment: This disables Selinux and the security it provides, since i don't know the specific setup. i cannot say much about this, but look at this link instead to fix that problem in general. https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/
# SELinux serve files off Apache, resursive
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /data/www/html/sites/mysite -R
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /data/www/html/sites/mysite/logs -R
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /data/www/html/sites/mysite/uploads -R
Probably set execution selinux context also

Answer (score 0):

The folder needs to be writable also because pulling will actually write data. You can change the owner to apache if it's a web site repo(and you are using apache group or user as owner of the www root).

Comment: thank you Ivan, but this was the very first thing I did. all of the project workspace's owner is apache (it was clonned by this user) and I even changed .git directory (chmod -R 0777 .git) permissions to 0777. and it still says Permission denied.

Comment: Try copying the repo to another folder and chmod it to 0777(the whole repo folder is written upon) to test it out. There may be some misconfiguration and your scripts may not be executed under the same user as the folder owner.

Comment: Did that, put 0777 for the whole repo with no luck, still getting Permission denied :( It must be a problem with git

Comment: It can't be a git issue. Changing the repo owner to be www-data fixed it for me although my httpd executes under www-user(which is in www-data group).

Comment: Is it possible that git is trying to open some other file? it is not possible that the whole repo has 0777 and it could not be opened.

Comment: No, git is operating only in the repo folder. Can you list some example files/folders from the repo with permission data with "ls -l". This may help solve the issue.

Comment: Did you chmod with sudo? Also apply 777 not 0777. So "sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/repo"

Comment: no luck :( probably I will leave it and go with bash script run by cron :(

Comment: found the answer, selinux was the problem.