# GIT pulling as i am connected to ssh remote server

Tags: github, ssh, sh

Hi i'm having trouble pulling in a remote endpoint.

command to connect from remote google compute engine:

```
ssh -i /path/.ssh/google_compute_engine NAME@REMOTEIP "cd /home/repo/; git pull origin dev"
```

Connection via ssh to remote endpoint is working.
When i do manually my git pull is working but when i try to pass commands line as arguments it fail :

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Also if i try to add my ssh:

```
ssh -i /path/.ssh/google_compute_engine NAME@IP "cd /home/repo; ssh-add ~/.ssh/rsa_pub"
```

it fail:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

ssh -i /path/.ssh/google_compute_engine NAME@IP "ls /home; cd /home/repo; eval ssh-agent;"
```

return :

```
SSH_AGENT_PID=311; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 311;
```

I have to use it like this to make a script for production.

I don't find a way to do it, and also avoid entering passphrase so it will automatically pull as i launch of the command below.
Can i somehow pass my the rsa_pub as parameter ?

Comment: Might changing  the permissions in the .git directory like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56098268/7099374 do the trick?

Comment: Did not but thanks for the help
```drwxrwxrw- 8 user user    4096 Oct 23 16:42 .git```

Permission denied (publickey) still

Comment: start with the remote command `pwd; whoami`. This will tell you the user context setup by SSH. Then adjust as necessary. Linux has the command `runuser` so that you can specify the user environment for commands.

Answer (score 0):

Servers from some providers like AWS will not log you in as root but rather as a user with limited permissions (i.e. ubuntu@ip) try adding `sudo` before `git pull` on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it give me 
```Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.```