# Permission Denied Error Git using Azure VM

Tags: git, azure, azure-virtual-machine

In attempting to use with what I'm familiar (as I'm not a huge fan of the Visual Studio git GUI) I've been attempting to use git bash inside our developer environments, which happen to be VMs in Azure.  The VMs are set up with different admin logins than my company email in Azure AD (which is what I use to log in to our Azure Repos) but, in the past, I've simply entered my credentials the first time into the prompt after performing a clone, fetch, pull, etc and had no trouble from that point forward.

This time, however, I'm continually being asked to log in again, first with the Microsoft popup and then the SSH screen to verify my credentials.  Within the same stroke of creating a new branch, committing, pushing those changes to the remote, logging in, and then switching to another development branch, after I perform a pull (within seconds of the prior log in to push) I'm being asked for credentials *again*, it not outright given this message: `error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied`

I've looked around on the forum, [tried some of the most popular solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195814/trying-to-git-pull-with-error-cannot-open-git-fetch-head-permission-denied), and haven't found a solution that works as of yet.  It's on a Windows 10 VM, running a Dynamics (X++) project, but otherwise just a regular git setup, or so I've been lead to believe!

Has anyone run into a similar situation, and if so, what worked for you?  Thank you!

Comment: You tried any of this yet? https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials