# Can't change rbenv global ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

I switched from RVM to rbenv recently and I can't seem to switch between ruby versions even though 'rbenv versions' tells me I have the version I want to switch to.

Here is what Im doing:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

I would like to switch to 1.9.2-p290 so lets make sure I have it in my versions:

```
ruby versions
1.8.7-p370
1.9.2-p290
1.9.3-p125
1.9.3-rc1
```

Ok great now that I see I have it lets try and change the global rbenv:

```
rbenv global 1.9.2-p290
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

Seems 1.8.7 is still the active global ruby.

So, lets try and make it local in my project. 
    rbenv local 1.9.2-p290

This creates a .rbenv-versions file in my rails project. Great lets try and run bundle:

```
Gem::InstallError: factory_girl requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
An error occurred while installing factory_girl (4.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install factory_girl -v '4.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm not sure what to do next...

Comment: Ok so I *Think* I figured out the issue. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version/11708787#11708787

But that wasn't quite the issue cause I only have one 0.3.0 version. So i removed it anyways and put a local copy on my desktop. 

Ran rbevn global [change] and obviously it didn't work.

I put the same file back in and then ran the change global ruby command back and it fixed whatever issue I was having.

Comment: It is so curious that questions like this stay unanswered. Me and most people I know really struggle just getting a different Ruby version to work on OSX. And somehow, it seems impossible to find the right answers, even on Github.

Comment: Since this still shows up in 2021, what worked for me was to add these commands in the terminal:

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"

eval "$(rbenv init -)"

Answer (score 5):

I solved this today on a (OSX) computer of a friend, the problem probably is that you have RVM and Rbenv installed at the same time, first you have to make sure RVM is removed;

In the terminal execute:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

When this is done, reopen the terminal. Then try `ruby -v`, the version you see is probably the system version **ruby 1.8.7**. Then try again to select the right Ruby version with Rbenv:

```
rbenv global 2.0.0-p247
```

Also, be sure Rbenv is in your path:

```
echo $PATH
=> /Users/jankeesvw/.rbenv/bin:/Users/jankeesvw/.rbenv/shims:/Users/jankeesvw/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

If this Rbenv is not in your path, follow the instructions on the [Rbenv github page](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)

Comment: You are, as promised when I tweeted you this question, my hero. Finally my Ruby is not 1.8.7 anymore. One of the many, many gotchas was modifying .zshrc instead of .bash_profile. (Next challenge is rake jasmine, but that's not part of this question.)

Comment: If the PATH has no .rbenv then execute:

Answer (score 3):

If `$ echo $PATH`

has no .rbenv then execute:

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

and restart shell.

Comment: And for ~/.zshr substitute for~/.bash_profile like thisc$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zschr
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zschr worked for me.