# rbenv can't change global ruby version

Tags: ruby, rbenv

My Mac OS X has a default ruby.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

I installed rbenv and ruby version 2.1.2.

```
$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.1.2 (set by /Users/sdw/.rbenv/version)
```

and I tried to set the global ruby version to 2.1.2, but nothing happened.

```
$ rbenv global 2.1.2
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

So I tried to do the same thing with command `sudo`, but the result is the same.

```
$ sudo rbenv global 2.1.2
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

How can I change my global ruby version to 2.1.2? I never installed rvm or other ruby version managing system.

Comment: These questions might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884110/cant-change-rbenv-global-ruby-version and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Did you add the following lines to your `~/.bash_profile`?

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

See: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installation

Comment: this answer is no longer correct for recent versions of rbenv; see more recent question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199156/why-do-i-need-to-add-rbenv-bin-to-my-path#40204828

Comment: @dcorking: I am not sure if I agree with your comment. First, at the moment rbenv's documentation still tells to add that line. Second, that folder does exist on my machine. I guess it depends on how someone installed rbenv.

Comment: rbenv's documentation is inconsistent and does not recommend this at all for homebrew installations. At the next step of github checkout, it says "Run ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init" which makes prepending `bin` to the path unnecessary. Let's try without homebrew and submit a Pull Request.

Comment: See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: This worked for me too. Added this to my ~/.zshrc

Comment: On Mac OS High Sierra & this worked.

Comment: Adding `eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"` to `~/.zshrc` was all it took for me.

Answer (score 13):

Type `$ rbenv version` (without "s")

It is possible that output will show a path to the file that is locking the version

```
2.0.0p451 (set by /path/to/some/directory/.ruby-version)
```

It is even possible that the file is a hidden file named `.ruby-version` in your current dir. If its the case just remove that `.ruby-version` file

Comment: In my case this was the correct answer, thank you @Benj

Comment: This is the case for me - `/.ruby-version` specifies 2.5.5. But the thing is, that's the version that I _want_. And it's also what my local version is set to, through rbenv. And yet, when I try to install gems or run `ruby -v`, I get 2.3.7 and I can't figure out why. :/

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some reason, my `~` folder had a .ruby-version file.

Answer (score 7):

Run the below commands before change ruby version:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

It works for me :)

Answer (score 7):

Uninstall ruby and then install agains:

```
brew uninstall -f ruby
brew install ruby
```

Add this two line to you ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Reopen the console and that's it and run

```
ruby -v
```

Comment: Works for Ruby v3.1.3

Answer (score 3):

I realize that I occasionally set local ruby version in home folder, from which I use terminal by default :)
So that's what worked for me:

```
rm /home/MYUSERNAME/.ruby-version
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue ("ruby -v" showing the initial version) but reloading (exit/start) my terminal made the trick.

Did you try that first?

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing ruby on rails on ubuntu,and you rbenv doesn't change your ruby version

```
> rbenv list # This lists all the rbenv versions available
```

- 2.6.8
- 2.7.4
- 3.0.2
- jruby-9.3.1.0
- mruby-3.0.0
- rbx-5.0
  -truffleruby-21.3.0
  -truffleruby+graalvm-21.3.0

> In my case I need to install ruby 3.0.2

```
rbenv install 3.0.2
```

> After this also it shows ruby v [2.7.0-]

```
rbenv global 3.0.2
```

This will help you change your ruby version.

Answer (score -2):

instead of:
rbenv global 2.7.1
do: 
sudo rbenv global 2.7.1

Comment: OP already tried this: "So I tried to do the same thing with command sudo, but the result is the same."

Comment: It worked for me, my reasoning was 'benv global' needed permissions to update. If I find out something new I'll let you know.