# rbenv global and ruby -v return different versions?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I have a situation where

```
rbenv global
2.7.1
```

But

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

I've tried `rbenv rehash`, but it didn't seem to alter anything.

How do I get the default global version of ruby to be `2.7.1` ?

Answer (score 1):

Is the environment variable `RBENV_VERSION` set to anything? I second [what stevec said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62576247/2383169), but also keep in mind that the version will also be set to the value of `RBENV_VERSION`, which you may have set for your current session if you ran `ruby shell VERSION_NUM`. `RBENV_VERSION` takes precedence over all else: stackoverflow.com/a/12150580

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a terrible answer that doesn't show a full understanding of the situation, but what worked for me was:

- if using zsh, any Stack Overflow answers saying to do something to bash files should instead be done to zsh files - i.e. inspect these files `~/.zshenv` and `~/.zshrc` (not their bash equivalents)
- I then corrected for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40204828/5783745) problem - that is, commented out the first line

The closed and reopened zsh (terminal) and suddenly `ruby -v` returned the desired `2.7.1`

Note: there was another problem, outside my app, `ruby -v` was 2.7.1, but inside the app directly, it was still returning 2.5.1, that was due to a file called `.ruby-version`, which needed to be updated. Now that I look back on this problem, I think that was the *only* problem