# rbenv global doesn't set ruby

Tags: macos, rbenv

Im using OSX 10.8.4

I have tried setting my global ruby version using:

```
$ rbenv global 1.9.3-p429

$ rbenv version
>> 1.9.3-p194 (set by /Users/emailnitram/.ruby-version)
```

My PATH looks like this:

`/Users/emailnitram/.rbenv/shims:/Users/emailnitram/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/emailnitram/Sites/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/emailnitram/.rbenv/shims:/Users/emailnitram/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/emailnitram/Sites/bin`

I have tried looking at [rbenv not changing ruby version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version) and followed the instructions to ensure I have the following in my ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Still I usually have to set `rbenv local 1.9.3-p429` to get it to work

Comment: same issue with me...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when installing ruby 2.6.5 today. 
Reinstalled rbenv, cleaned up my bash_profile, bashrc, and zshrc (I use zsh) from any `rbenv` keyword. Start fresh.

I still had the same problem, but turns out after `rbenv install 2.6.5` (or whatever version you run), you need to run [rehash](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-rehash) (`rbenv rehash`).

After that, when I do `ruby -v`, it would show latest and everything works