# rbenv: ruby: command not found

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I am using rbenv with ruby version 1.9.1-p378 on the local dir.

Command **ruby -v** gives the following error:

```
rbenv: ruby: command not found

The `ruby' command exists in these Ruby versions:
2.0.0-p353
```

Any clue why this happens? The bundle, rails commands do not work either.

Command **rbenv versions**  :

```
* 1.9.1-p378 (set by /home/user/Desktop/r1/noko1/.ruby-version)
2.0.0-p353
```

Comment: As you can see: the `ruby` app exists only in ruby 2.0.0 version, not in 1.9.1, just switch ruby to 2.0.0

Comment: You really (really) don't want to use Ruby 1.9.1 as it is broken in multiple regards (encoding, rubygems, ...) and is generally not supported by anyone. You should use at least Ruby 1.9.2 if you want to use a 1.9 Ruby.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73418391/551744

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1. The complaint you get comes from rbenv. The fact that it's complaining shows that rbenv is set up and working.
2. Figure out what version of Ruby is needed to run the project. Either the project comes with a .ruby-version file in the root, or someone on the project will know and recommend that version to use.
3. If the version is not specified in a .ruby-version file, create the .ruby-version file in the project directory.
4. type `ruby -v` while in that directory. Is it OK? Then you have the version of Ruby installed that matches what your .ruby-version is asking for.
5. If the last command was not OK, then type `rbenv install`.

Now that Ruby is installed, you need to run your program. I'm assuming it comes with a Rakefile.

1. install the bundler tool: `gem install bundler`.
2. install the dependancies of the project: `bundle install`
3. run your project using the exact versions of libraries it specifies: `bundle exec rails server`

Comment: I'm trying to run an application that is giving me problems when i try to run it with 2.0.0.  Something about rbconfig/config.  That's why I'm trying to use it with 1.9.1.  It is also using rails 2.3.2, which I gather from the gemfile of the app. However the rails command also does not work...

Comment: I have made step by step instructions. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, [rbenv install] to get rubygems working - and then [gem install bundler] were big helps. However I had about 4 or 5 other things to fix including adding [gem rdoc] to the gemfile and installing a few other required gems like sqlite, etc, and finally downgrading the rubygems version again in order to use ./script/server start for rails 2.3.2 ; but after all that it WORKS! Thanks a bundle

Comment: For those still running into this issue, try and close your terminal first and trying again. Worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

Try the following piece of code depending on the current version of rails that you have installed. In my case am using `v2.3.3`

```
rbenv global 2.3.3
```

Comment: As someone who is completely unfamiliar with Ruby, this is the only thing that has worked for me,

Comment: I had to do this to tell rbenv what version of ruby to use. Insert whatever version you installed using rbenv install x.y[.z] (in my case 2.7.0). Now ruby -v works as expected

Answer (score 3):

Even setting global or local doesn't work if you haven't set this

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
exec $SHELL
```

Answer (score 1):

Even there is correct answer above, but it is not clear for my first check, so give a complete answer as a summarize based on z5h and Thengugi's answer.
After setup and install ruby using rbenv as below (I installed 2.5.0):

```
rbenv install 2.5.0
```

You also need set it as the default version in your OS (CentOS for me):

```
rbenv global 2.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to `rbenv install` the ruby version you want to use, since only `2.0.0-p353` is available. See `rbenv help`.

Comment: I thought it was installed, see my edit, when i use rbenv versions

Comment: Can you share your `.rbenv-version` file in the desired directory?

Comment: It just has the one line :  1.9.1-p378

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Please make gem as a global using rbenv global ruby-version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue `rbenv: ruby: command not found` and it was eventually solved by removing the rbenv-bundler plugin. This plugin is [considered harmful](https://github.com/carsomyr/rbenv-bundler/issues/32) and removing it is as simple as `rm -rf $RBENV_ROOT/plugins/bundler` then run `rm -rf $(rbenv root)/shims && rbenv rehash`