# the rails' command exists in these ruby versions 2.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby version 2.2.3 which I've upgraded from 2.1.5. The problem is when I try to execute any Rails command it won't execute and give me this error

> the rails' command exists in these ruby versions 2.1.5

So when I switched back to my previous version by rbenv global 2.1.5, it is working again. Can anyone tell me whats going on here? Why I can't do anything with newer version of ruby?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rbenv: ruby: command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275951/rbenv-ruby-command-not-found)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe try to do a gem install rails with your new version.