# rbenv: bundler: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

In a bid to run a Rails App on my local Ubuntu, I attempted to install the gems with the command `gem install bunder` / `bundle install`. However, I got the error:

> rbenv: bundler: command not found . The `bundler' command exists in these Ruby versions:
>
> 2.4
> 2.4.1
> 2.4.2
> 2.4.5
> 2.5
> 2.5.0
> 2.5.1
> 2.5.3
> 2.5.7
> 2.5.8
> 2.6
> 2.6.0
> 2.6.1
> 2.6.3
> 2.6.4
> 2.6.5
> 2.6.6
> 2.6.7
> 2.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by running the command `gem install bundler` in the root directory of the rails app.

Answer (score 0):

in my specific case, I was dealing with an old Ruby version

I had to first install bundler
`gem install bundler`
then it complained that it needed a specific old version:
`To install the missing version, run gem install bundler:1.17.3`
installing that specific old version fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

OS X: `brew install rbenv`
Debian `apt-get install rbenv`
Ubuntu `apt-get install rbenv`
Kali Linux `apt-get install rbenv`
Raspbian `apt-get install rbenv`

https://command-not-found.com/rbenv

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, for every new version of ruby you install, you are expected to install a fresh bundler.