# Ruby version issues with Rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version, bundle, rbenv

I am setting up my new machine (Mac Yosemite) and when I run the command "bundle" I get the following error:

> Your Ruby version is 2.2.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.0

I'm trying to change the version w Rbenv but I think it's not working.

```
ruby -v
// Ruby 2.2.1p85

rbenv version
// 2.2.0
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use rbenv local `[version number]`.Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version) for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with ruby -v 2.2.0 and Mac OSX El Capitan.  What finally worked for me was:

1. gem install bundler (apparently it was no longer installed)
2. rbenv rehash
3. bundle install

I was able to find the answer on the github for rbenv. 
[https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/697](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/697http://)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Ruby -v 2.2.0 installed (`rbenv install 2.2.0` otherwise), change your ruby version with `rbenv`:

```
rbenv global 2.2.0
```

after install rails you must do this: `rbenv rehash`, in order to tell `rbenv` to see `rails` as executable.

follow this tutorial to set up Ruby and Ruby on Rails in your machine: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite

Note: In my case. after install `rbenv` the command `rbenv global 2.2.0` doesn't affect my current ruby version (`ruby -v` still be the previous one). I fix this issue reinstalling `rbenv` and run this command:

```
# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

immediately afterwards, as explained above in the tutorial.