# Ruby Version Inconsistent

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv, middleman

I am trying to run bundle install, but when I do, I get a message indicating that my Gemfile specifies Ruby version 2.1.4 (which is correct), but that I am on Ruby 2.0.0 (which is not correct).  Please see the snippet from the terminal below.

```
~/D/g/prototype git:master ❯❯❯ bundle install
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/shell/basic.rb:355: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.4

~/D/g/prototype git:master ❯❯❯ rbenv versions                                                                ⏎
system
2.0.0-p195
* 2.1.4 (set by /Users/jasenlew/Desktop/glowing/prototype/.ruby-version)
 2.2.0

~/D/g/prototype git:master ❯❯❯ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [x86_64-darwin14.0]

~/D/g/prototype git:master ❯❯❯ rbenv local
2.1.4

~/D/g/prototype git:master ❯❯❯ rbenv global
2.1.4
```

What am I missing?  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Did you run **rbenv shell 2.1.4** before bundle install?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12150580/2035262

Comment: No I did not; however, when I did type "rbenv shell 2.1.4" into command line and run, and then do "bundle install"... still get same issue.  Thanks Abhi, what do you think now?

Comment: @mudasobwa You rock!!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Got it resolved via that previous questions.  Thanks again so much!