# rbenv ruby on rails global vs local vs shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

```
// Start background info.
```

I just want to install ruby on rails for development (OSX El Capitan).

Pain point:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError) 
>   You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Solution: Installed *rbenv* to manage / modify a separate ruby.

rbenv is currently using my system ruby - so I've downloaded an identical version through rbenv install.

```
// end background info.
```

**Actual Question**: Do I set rbenv local, global or shell ruby version to the newly downloaded version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `rbenv` does the dirty work for you [if loaded correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version), but if you need to change the *global* setting, you can always update it:

```
rbenv global 2.3.0
```

Then you can check that's properly applied with:

```
rbenv versions
```

The `*` indicates the currently active `ruby`. Test with:

```
ruby -v
```

That should be the version you're asking for.

Using `rbenv` is a lot better than the system ruby, so I hope it works out for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was wondering whether to change the version globally, locally or shell specific. I ended up changing it globally, I was just scared to make the change before.

Comment: Each method is valid depending on the circumstances, that's why there's options. `global` is what you use by default, so set it to your favourite. `local` is project-specific, best used with legacy code that can't be upgraded yet.

Comment: This thread cleared up a lot for me. For someone who has been groping in the dark, is there a way to id which version of ruby is used locally and which is used globally? Also: Is there a "best practice" to "fix" a ruby version when one begins a new rails project?

Comment: `rbenv global` tells you the global version, `rbenv local` the local one if any such version is set.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official rbenv documentation in Github, their differences are the following:

```
# Sets a local application-specific Ruby version
# by writing the version name to a `.ruby-version`.
$ rbenv local <version>

# Sets the global version of Ruby to be used in all shells
# by writing the version name to the `~/.rbenv/version` file
$ rbenv global <version>

# Sets a shell-specific Ruby version by setting the
# RBENV_VERSION environment variable in your shell.
# This for temporary use and will only work during the terminal session
$ rbenv shell <version>
```

Note that your terminal session will no longer respect any .ruby-version files. You need to run rbenv shell --unset to enable the auto switch again.

Happy Coding :)