# Cocoapods: Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.0.1

When running `pod repo update` the following error is generated:

```
Updating spec repo `master`
[!] Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo - Please check if you are offline, or that GitHub is down
```

Using cocoapods 1.0.1

I'm also aware of this: [Master spec-repo rate limiting post‑mortem](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Master-Spec-Repo-Rate-Limiting-Post-Mortem/).

Adding --verbose flag to the call shows the ruby call stack:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods-core/github.rb:100:in `modified_since_commit'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods-core/master_source.rb:32:in `requires_update?'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods-core/master_source.rb:14:in `update'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:88:in `block (2 levels) in update'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:63:in `section'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:87:in `block in update'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:86:in `each'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:86:in `update'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/update.rb:23:in `run'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/pod:23:in `load'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Can't find any way to workaround this and cannot run the project.

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7447#issuecomment-368245483, it's related to older Ruby version

Answer (score 421):

One of the major issue is "weak cryptographic standards removed" after 2018 February.

Here a note:
https://github.com/blog/2507-weak-cryptographic-standards-removed

To solve this, first you need to update openssl, then ruby, then cocoapod.

```
$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl

$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

$ brew update

$ brew install openssl

$ brew upgrade openssl

`` If you need to have this software first in your PATH run: echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile

$ which openssl
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl

$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017

$ brew install rbenv ruby-build

$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile

$ rbenv install --list

Available versions:
  1.8.5-p52
  1.8.5-p113
  1.8.5-p114
  1.8.5-p115
  1.8.5-p231
  1.8.6
:
  2.5.0-rc1
  2.5.0
  2.5.1
  2.6.0-dev
:

$ rbenv install 2.5.1

$ rbenv versions
* system (set by /Users/username/.rbenv/version)
  2.5.1

$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]

$ rbenv global 2.5.1

$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.5.1 (set by /Users/username/.rbenv/version)

$ ruby --version
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin16]

$ gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin

$ which pod
/usr/local/bin/pod

$ pod --version
1.5.3
```

now, you can do

```
$ pod update
```

source link: https://qiita.com/satoshi-iwaki/items/ed2c267127dcc80baa21

Comment: it should be `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"` and not `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Is there are reason why you're installing version 2.1.0 of ruby? Why not the latest?

Comment: there is not particular reason. newer version would probably work, but 2.1.0 seems working. so, I dont want to risk higher version

Comment: I followed this advice to the keystroke, along with every other suggested answer in this thread... to no avail. I've blown away the Cocoapods repo so many times. Any long shots or crazy ideas out there?

Comment: You should use a newer Ruby version because of this:
"WARNING: ruby-2.1.0 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates."

Comment: I used ruby 2.2.9 and it worked, although I get a warning about nearing end of life.

Comment: Also had to do rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/ before running pod repo update

Comment: @Adem i am getting this error "Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools" can you help me ? Full Error : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Y8Z99NXmVz/

Comment: Without restarting also it works for me, thanks to @Adem

Comment: Note that Podfile version `1.5.0.beta.1` doesn't work for me.
Execute this command `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` and select 1.5.0.beta.1 to remove this version

Comment: I'm getting this error :- $ rbenv install 2.5.0
ruby-build: use openssl from homebrew
Downloading ruby-2.5.0.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.5/ruby-2.5.0.tar.bz2
error: failed to download ruby-2.5.0.tar.bz2

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.12.6 using ruby-build 20180329)

Comment: install cocoapods it should be : sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 141):

Finally managed to solve it by deleting `./cocoapods/repos/master` and running `pod install`.

The more formal solution would probably go like this:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install
```

If `pod install` fails after performing the first two steps, you may need to delete your `Podfile.lock`.

Why it initially failed to connect to Github is beyond me.

Comment: Happened to me after changing ssh keys. As one of the possible reasons.

Comment: I did all the 3 steps but still it shows [!] Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo - Please check if you are offline, or that GitHub is down

Comment: deleting "Podfile.lock" file and then executing "pod install" worked for me! Thanks

Comment: it's `~/.cocoapods` not `./cocoapods`

Comment: That works for me, changing 'master' for the user whom I want to delete

Answer (score 52):

You can try this:

```
$sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
$pod setup
$pod install
```

but in my case I had to:

- delete the Podfile.lock and then
- `$pod install`

Answer (score 43):

A another solution similar to [Max's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48996424/1437653) and [Adem's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48962041/1437653) in this thread is found in a [CocoaPods issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7447#issuecomment-368282524):

```
brew install ruby
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

[Verify that you're using the latest and correct Ruby with:](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7447#issuecomment-368245483)

```
ruby --version
which ruby
```

Should be using `/usr/local/bin/ruby`

**Reason:**
It turns out that [Github updated to only support TLS 1.2 on Feb 22nd.](https://twitter.com/grantaholliday/status/966757304640028672) Older versions of MacOS before High Sierra come preinstalled with Ruby 2.0. This version uses OpenSSL 0.9.8 which ["will fail with servers supporting only TLS 1.2."](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7447#issuecomment-367858136)

Updating to the latest Ruby (2.5) and latest CocoaPods (1.4) fixed this for me without having to do anything with openssl (Ruby updates openssl). This is a good solution if you don't want to update to High Sierra just yet.

Comment: This didn't fix it for me, but I voted up for the background explanation.

Comment: Important detail: I had CocoaPods installed via brew. In that case upgrading Ruby and openssl wasn't sufficient. I had to uninstall CocoaPods and then reinstall it via `gem` as shown in this answer.

Answer (score 22):

I also encountered the same issue. In my scene, i used a mirror repo (hosted elsewhere) of cocoapods specs on github. When i updated the specs repo, it worked!

```
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
git pull
```

Comment: I was getting the offline/github down error thing as well and this is what worked. I was a little hesitant to uninstall pods.

Answer (score 15):

This worked like magic

```
$sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
$pod setup
$pod install
```

Otherwise

```
$pod setup
Ctrl +C
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos 
$git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

Answer (score 8):

A slightly simpler solution from Adem's that doesn't use rbenv:

```
brew install openssl
brew upgrade openssl
brew install ruby
brew link --overwrite ruby
```

Finally, make sure you don't have your `PATH` variable set to have `/usr/local/bin` *after* `$PATH`. Your `PATH` export in `~/.bash_profile` should look similar to this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: This what also was enough for me. Note that you still need to re-install cocoapods by running `gem install cocoapods` as each ruby has its own gem location. BTW, there's no need to run the `brew install openssl` step as it's a dependency of ruby anyway.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

1. Remove `Podfile.lock`
2. Run `pod install`

Answer (score 7):

Just update cocoapods: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Answer (score 2):

If someone has these issues on Circle CI I was struggling with this for a day almost.

In the end I think the best way is to use their provided solution to download from their servers.

```
curl https://cocoapods-specs.circleci.com/fetch-cocoapods-repo-from-s3.sh | bash -s cf
```

From this link you can see that one of the cocoapods core contributor says that it's fine: 
The CocoaPods repo cache is updated roughly every 30 mins, which is usually frequent enough to only miss the last 6 pushes to the Specs repo.

https://discuss.circleci.com/t/best-practice-for-use-of-cached-cocoapods-specs/18897/2

Answer (score 0):

I did next in Terminal:

1. brew install openssl

   if you don't have home brew:

   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

   and repeat p.1
2. export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
3. openssl version

   Output:OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
4. pod update

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem.
I solved it only by accessing two commands from terminal.

> sudo gem uninstall nanaimo

and then

> sudo gem install nanaimo

Hope so it will help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all of cocoapods package. <sup>*[See here](https://superuser.com/questions/686317/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-cocoapods-from-the-mac-machine) for information on how to do this.*</sup>
2. Then reinstall cocoapods. `$ sudo gem install cocoapods`

Answer (score 0):

For me the below commands fixed the issue

**Removing cocoapods from mac**

```
 sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

**Installing cocoapods on mac**

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone facing any similar issue where the remote hangs-up prematurely, use `ssh` to clone the repo instead.

git clone git@github.com:CocoaPods/Specs.git master.

In order to use SSH to clone a GitHub repo, you need to have a GitHub account and have your SSH keys associated with it.

[Follow their documentation here](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-ssh-urls).

Answer (score 0):

- update ruby and cocoapods.
- check ruby version in the cocoapods env.

use

```
pod env
```

[image]

```
rbenv global x.x.x
ruby -v
```

change ruby version. If not working, watch this [rbenv not changing ruby version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version)

check ruby version in the cocoapods env. If not changed,

```
which pod
```

make sure your pod path is `/usr/local/bin/pod`,if not

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```