# Not able to update pod. Always getting error GitHub is down

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am using `pod --version` 1.3.1, OS: macOS Sierra (10.12.6)

when I am trying to update pod using the command:

```
$ pod update
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
[!] Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo - Please check if you are offline, or that GitHub is down
```

I am always getting above error from yesterday and still not found any proper solution.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this [Thread](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7447#issuecomment-368245483)

Comment: reinstall pod https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993527/cocoapods-failed-to-connect-to-github-to-update-the-cocoapods-specs-specs-repo

Comment: I installed first brew using /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" then pod install. works for me. Thanks.

Comment: make sure you have the most recent software

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Install **[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)** using below command.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)”
```

> 2. install ruby using — >  `brew install ruby`
> 3. `sudo gem install cocoapods`
> 4. Check ruby version —> `ruby --version`
> 5. `which ruby`
> 6. `pod update`