# Updating Pod is not Working

Tags: ios, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.0.1

I know this question is previously asked and I review that asked question answers but still I am facing this error.

> [!] Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs
>   repo - Please check if you are offline, or that GitHub is down

Previously before a week ago `pod update` command is working fine but now when I run that command it gives me same error everyTime.

**I tried below solutions.**

1. I tried this command with multiple internet connection.

2.

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install
```

3.

```
$sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
$pod setup
$pod install
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried pod deintegrate ??

Comment: yes, remove cocoapods from project and reinstall again but still getting same error. I am getting this error in every project wether it's old or newly created.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoapods: Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993527/cocoapods-failed-to-connect-to-github-to-update-the-cocoapods-specs-specs-repo)

Comment: I was able to solve it by installing latest version of ruby. Thank you

Comment: @JayeshThanki,  as I mentioned that I tried given answer but still I am getting same error. I also tried given answers.

Comment: did you upgrade mac os?

Comment: @JayeshThanki, no, my Mac OS is macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Comment: @Kuldeep could you try pod --version and see if you are getting version or error.
If you are getting the error could you try ruby --version

Comment: please update cocoapods using this command `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Comment: @JayeshThanki let me try this command.

Comment: @AravindAR how to install ruby?

Comment: @JayeshThanki I tried `sudo gem install cocoapods` 1 gem installed but  when I run `pod repo update` or `pod update` same error occur.

Comment: Update Ruby & Update CocoaPods (search how to do it for each of them individually), that did the trick for me, on macOS 10.12.6, old version Mac created the issue I think.

Comment: very very thanks @Kuldeep https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49166609/updating-pod-is-not-working?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found solution from [satoshi-iwaki](https://qiita.com/satoshi-iwaki).

This error occurs because

> GitHub invalidated vulnerable SSL / TSL on 2018/23.

**1. Install (or update) Homebrew.**

> ```
> $ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
>
> $ brew update
> ```

**2. Install (or update) OpenSSL.**

> ```
> $ brew install openssl
>
> $ brew upgrade openssl
> ```

In the log at the time of installation `openssl` because the path of the output, in the street `PATH` wo `.bash_profileso` as to set in.

> If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
> `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`
>
> `$ source ~/.bash_profile`

**3. Check the version.**

> `$ which openssl`

/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl

> `$ openssl version`

OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017

**4. Make sure you can access with TLSv 1.2.**

> $ openssl s_client -connect api.github.com:443

gives log like this.
[image]

**5.Installing Ruby**

Since I want to install Ruby separately from Ruby on the system, I install it so that it can be switched rbenv.

> ```
> $ brew install rbenv ruby-build 
>
> $ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile 
>
> $ echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
>
> $ source ~/.bash_profile
> ```

**6.Check the version of Ruby to install.**

> $ rbenv install --list

gives list of Available versions.

**Install Ruby.**

> $ rbenv install 2.1.0

**Switch the version.**

> $ rbenv global 2.1.0

**7. Install CocoaPods.**

> $ gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin

**If you want to check pods version**

> $ pod --version

**Confirm that pod update ends normally.**

> $ pod update

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved all my problems !