# CocoaPods import module not existing

Tags: module, cocoapods, sdwebimage

Issue started after installing SDWebImage, installed firebase and progressHUD which worked fine but cant import SDWebImage and now i cant install any Pods, they show same error. The new folder exists in Pods folder and pod file same as other pod installs.

import UIKit

import FirebaseDatabase

import FirebaseStorage

import SDWebImage

error message: No such module 'SDWebImage'

Comment: "and now i cant install any Pods, they show same error" What error? "Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo - Please check if you are offline, or that GitHub is down"? If that's the case, first it would be good to give us the error, and else, I suppose you haven't the last macOS version. You need to update Ruby and CocoaPods (and maybe OpenSSL, don't remember), but you could search that error on SO, it has been answered.

Comment: See there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49166609/updating-pod-is-not-working You don't have to use Brew if you didn't installed it previously, there are alternative for each update without HomeBrew.