# How can I get the token from Firebase Cloud Messaging on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Podfile**

```
target 'T' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod ‘Firebase’
  pod ‘Firebase/Auth’
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end
```

**imports in AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging
```

**AppDelegate**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate
```

Running Xcode 9.2, compiler language version swift 4, deployment target 11.2

According to the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client i should be able to use the following

```
1) Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
2) func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
   print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
 }

3) FIRMessageDelegate
```

however xcode does not recognize 
-'Messaging' class from 1)
-'FIRMessageDelegate' from 3)
-or the delegate method from 2)

because of that i am not able to get the fcmtoken which my app needs

Xcode does recognize these but these are not in the documentation so i dont know what to do

```
4) FIRMessagingDelegate
5) FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
```

and the only delegate method in 4) is

```
func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage)
    {
        print(remoteMessage.appData)
    }
```

**My question is: How can i get the token? The documentation seems outdated.**

**podfile.lock**

```
PODS:
  - Firebase (3.15.0):
    - Firebase/Core (= 3.15.0)
  - Firebase/Auth (3.15.0):
    - Firebase/Core
    - FirebaseAuth (= 3.1.1)
  - Firebase/Core (3.15.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 3.7.0)
    - FirebaseCore (= 3.5.2)
  - Firebase/Database (3.15.0):
    - Firebase/Core
    - FirebaseDatabase (= 3.1.2)
  - Firebase/Messaging (3.15.0):
    - Firebase/Core
    - FirebaseMessaging (= 1.2.2)
  - Firebase/Storage (3.15.0):
    - Firebase/Core
    - FirebaseStorage (= 1.1.0)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (3.7.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 3.5)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
  - FirebaseAuth (3.1.1):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.7)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (~> 2.1)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - FirebaseCore (3.5.2):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
  - FirebaseDatabase (3.1.2):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.7)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.9)
  - FirebaseMessaging (1.2.2):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.7)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (~> 2.1)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
  - FirebaseStorage (1.1.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.7)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/DebugUtils (2.1.1):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.1)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (2.1.1)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (2.1.1):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.1)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (2.1.1):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.1)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (2.1.1):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/DebugUtils (= 2.1.1)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.1)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (= 2.1.1)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (2.1.1)
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (1.1.9)
  - Protobuf (3.2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in appdelegate

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications






@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var fcmTokenUser : String?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()


        print(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last! as String)


        // To get FCM token that will be sent to APNS via Google FCM
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken





        return true
    }



    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String){
         // This callback is fired at each app startup (when the user install the app for the very first time) and whenever a new token is generated due to The app is restored on a new device, The user uninstalls/reinstall the app, The user clears app data.

        // after fcm generated for the very first time,then fcm can also be retrieved in the 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' method above (let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken)


        fcmTokenUser = fcmToken






    }


    private func application(application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
    }





}
```

pod file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target  do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for HRIS

 pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
 pod 'FirebaseInstanceID'






end
```

Comment: Nothing changed still not recognized

Comment: are you using latest version of Firebase? it seems that you install Firebase 3 instead of 4, as far as I know the latest Firebase protocol and class will no longer Use FIR prefix, just use MessagingDelegate  instead of FIRMessagingDelegate

Answer (score 0):

Solution is that pod install was installing version older versions of firebase. The up to date version is 4 but pod install was installing version 3. So to fix i needed to do a pod update but the command was saying failing to connect to gitbub, so i did what this guy did here [Cocoapods: Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993527/cocoapods-failed-to-connect-to-github-to-update-the-cocoapods-specs-specs-repo) and then pod update worked and firebase was upgraded

Answer (score 0):

A while ago, I just managed to successfully get the fcm token and sent out the notification to my phone from the firebase console.  Here is the whole code for the AppDelegage.  The code from firebase.com documentation seems to be outdated.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FirebaseApp.configure()


    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_,_ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as! 
UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self as! MessagingDelegate
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken


}






func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive 
state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as 
an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application 
and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate 
graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, 
invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore 
your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is 
called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active 
state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the 
application was inactive. If the application was previously in the 
background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if 
appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent 
notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: 
@escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)

}

}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: 
MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: 
String){

    print("token: \(fcmToken)")


}
}
```