# Firebase Unity iOS Uncaught exception: NSInvalidArgumentException: +[FIRApp registerLibrary:withVersion:]

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, unity-game-engine, build

Issue:

```
Uncaught exception: NSInvalidArgumentException: +[FIRApp registerLibrary:withVersion:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x101b94b98
```

[image: XCode error screenshot]

I have tried a lot of solutions but nothing worked. Let me give  you details about it

- Made iOS build from Unity 2017.3.0f3 by setting minimum target version 9.0
- Created `Podfile`:

  `$ cd your-project directory`

  `$ pod init`
- My `Podfile` is something like this

> ```
> # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
> # platform :ios, '9.0'
>
> target 'Unity-iPhone' do
>   # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
>   # use_frameworks!
>
>   # Pods for Unity-iPhone
>   pod 'GoogleInterchangeUtilities'
>   pod 'GoogleSymbolUtilities'
>   pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac'
>   pod 'Firebase'
>   pod 'Firebase/Core'
>   pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
>   pod 'Firebase/Auth'
>   pod 'Firebase/Storage'
>   pod 'Firebase/Database'
>
>   target 'Unity-iPhone Tests' do
>     inherit! :search_paths
>     # Pods for testing
>   end
>
> end
> ```

- Added `ObjC` `linker flag` in `Other Linker Settings` in target's build settings
- In the `Arguments Passed On Launch` section, added `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled`
- Added `AdSupport.framework` in `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section
- Then making a build by `.xcworkspace`, not `.xcodeproj`

So, tell me what I'm doing wrong?

- Isn't Firebase Unity plugins should work without any hassle of any settings like I did and in case of Android it does, everything by itself, just import plugin and you are good to go?

Comment: Show your firebase initialisation code for App Delegate

Comment: What you mean? do I have write something in App Delegate? I'm using Firebase Unity plugin, don't it will write everything by itself? 
By the way, i didn't write anything in App Delegate, if i have to write, then tell me what

Comment: This video might help you with your setup

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uj6rs3HFg5o

Make sure you are following this documentation. It seems you may have not read it properly

https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major issue was solved by updating `pod` following the steps provided in [this link (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993527/cocoapods-failed-to-connect-to-github-to-update-the-cocoapods-specs-specs-repo/48962041#48962041)

After that just do the following steps to make XCode project working, as `pod init` and `pod install` is done by Unity:

- Make XCode build from Unity by selecting `Xcode Workspace - Add Cocoapods to the Xcode workspace` from `iOS Resolver Settings`
- Open `.xcworkspace`, not `.xcodeproj`
- Add `-ObjC` [`Other Linker Flags`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks) in [target's build settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1490/_index.html)
- In case you are [using Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/analytics-adsupport) then you also have to add `AdSupport.framework` in `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section

At the end just have a look at the [Firebase Launch Checklist](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/launch-checklist)