# DJI iOS SDK 4.5 issue using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

I have trying to install DJI iOS SDK 4.5 using cocoapods in sample code downloaded from DJI website.

Every-time I try `pod install` it throws error saying

```
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "DJI-SDK-iOS":
In Podfile:
DJI-SDK-iOS (~> 4.5)
None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `DJI-SDK-iOS (~> 4.5)`
```

I even tried uninstalling cocoapods and reinstalling it again, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

> Error appeared because your source repository is out of date. You can resolve the issue by running:
>
> **pod install --repo-update**

---

> If this does not solve your problem, check if your cocoa-pods version is updated one. You can follow the below link for the same.

[update cocoapods version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993527/cocoapods-failed-to-connect-to-github-to-update-the-cocoapods-specs-specs-repo/48962041#48962041)

---

**Explanation:**

When you will run `pod install`, you will found the possible reason of this error as:

> None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `DJI-SDK-iOS (~> 4.5)`.
>
> **You have either:**
>
> - out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
> - mistyped the name or version.
> - not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
>
> **Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.**

Comment: I went through the same flow but I was not able to do the Pod update as it kept on throwing me 

Updating spec repo master [!] Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo - Please check if you are offline, or that GitHub is down

Now I am able to download after I followed steps in my answer.

Comment: That's because your pod version was out of date too. I think you have updated that by updating ruby environment of homebrew of your mac.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `pod install --repo-update` it was not able to update as it kept on throwing error

> Updating spec repo `master` [!] Failed to connect to GitHub to update
>   the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo - Please check if you are offline, or
>   that GitHub is down

Finally I found the solution my prob in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48962041/32140

After this  I was able to install the new pod version