# libusbmuxd version error during flutter install

Tags: git, installation, flutter

I'm having problems installing and configuring flutter

On mac OS Sierra 10.12.6

Xcode 9.2

brew doctor reported all ok

flutter doctor reported

[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.2)

```
✗ **libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller are not installed. To install, run:
    brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
    brew install ideviceinstaller**
```

prompt$: brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice

==> Cloning https://git.libimobiledevice.org/libimobiledevice.git
Updating /Users/rjoiner/Library/Caches/Homebrew/libimobiledevice--git

==> Checking out branch master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
HEAD is now at b34e343 tools: Remove length check on device UDID arguments to support newer devices

==> ./autogen.sh
Last 15 lines from /Users/rjoiner/Library/Logs/Homebrew/libimobiledevice/01.autogen.sh:
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin16.7.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin/pkg-config

checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for libusbmuxd >= 1.1.0... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libusbmuxd >= 1.1.0) were not met:

Requested 'libusbmuxd >= 1.1.0' but version of libusbmuxd is 1.0.10

I don't know how to install version 1.1.0 of libusbmuxd

Cheers

Rob

Comment: I got a bit further by re-installing and linking libmobiledevice, and brew doctor says your system is ready to brew.  ios-deploy cocoapods reports installed and up to date. pod setup gets this error: prompt$: pod setup
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!] Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo - Please check if you are offline, or that GitHub is down

Answer (score 113):

A [recent change](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/commit/f1ee0fd8b2b1dd65c64f5a67e208efc708295caa) to `libimobiledevice` [bumped the constraint](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/commit/f1ee0fd8b2b1dd65c64f5a67e208efc708295caa#diff-67e997bcfdac55191033d57a16d1408aL21) on libusbmuxd to >= version 1.1.0. The current `usbmuxd` homebrew package is version 1.0.10.

As a result, homebrew `--HEAD` installs of libimobiledevice no longer build without a `--HEAD` install of `usbmuxd`.

Until the `usbmuxd` homebrew formula is updated, a workaround is to install it at HEAD:

```
brew update
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies usbmuxd
brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
```

You can track progress on this issue on [flutter/flutter#22595](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22595).

Answer (score 14):

It's a bit odd, but it appears the formula for `libusbmuxd` is `usbmuxd`. Can you try `brew install --HEAD usbmuxd`?

Comment: It generates this message:  Error: usbmuxd 1.0.10_1 is already installed  To install HEAD_1, first run `brew unlink usbmuxd` -- brew doctor still reports your system is ready to brew

Comment: I went ahead and ran brew unlink usbmuxd and then brew install --HEAD usbmuxd all ok - ready to brew but running pod setup still errors with failed to connect  to GitHub when it has just been used to install usbmuxd  --- here is the full error Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!] Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo - Please check if you are offline, or that GitHub is down

Comment: It did work for me. I had to follow flutter doctor instructions after that to end up with a "all good" status but that mades it!

Answer (score 1):

This works to me in this exactly sequence :

```
brew update
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies usbmuxd
brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
brew unlink usbmuxd
brew link usbmuxd
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew install ideviceinstaller
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another thread that deals with the pod setup failing

I found this worked for me

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
```

[Cocoapods: Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993527/cocoapods-failed-to-connect-to-github-to-update-the-cocoapods-specs-specs-repo/48962041)