# I have a problem using validating my URL using cocoapods

Tags: github, frameworks, cocoapods

I am having a hard time creating a cocoa pods template and pushing it to GitHub because every time I access the terminal at the root to validate the pod using  :

```
               pod lib lint
```

I get the error message :

```
         url: There was a problem validating the URL https://github.com/Nathaniel Whittington/me.
```

Any reason why I keep getting this error message? And is the last version of brew cocoapods 1.11.0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cocoapods: Failed to connect to GitHub to update the CocoaPods/Specs specs repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993527/cocoapods-failed-to-connect-to-github-to-update-the-cocoapods-specs-specs-repo)

Comment: It seems that the URL has a space and it shouldn't. Maybe that's it?

Comment: @pietrorea thanks, ill look into that. been trying to get this cocoapods for hours now

Comment: @pietrorea how would I go about fixing that? In my regular projects, I don't have that issue.

Comment: Added an answer below

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is indeed the space in your URL, open your pod spec file and remove the space from `spec.source`. Here's some documentation:

https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html

Comment: I did have to change the spec.source, but for some reason, it's a completely different name from the one used in my Github account.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. @pietrorea