# cannot install latest Rails version on MacOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

I'm trying to install Rails 5 on my Mac (El Capitan).

When I type

```
gem install rails
```

I get this error message:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
```

When I check my Ruby version with Rbenv:

```
rbenv global
2.3.1
```

however when I check my Ruby version like this:

```
ruby -v
```

I get

```
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

how can I fix this, so when I want to install rails 5, it's using Ruby 2.3.1

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version

Comment: @Sravan how are commands for a different ruby version manager than they're using going to help?

Comment: yeah sry, removed that.

Comment: Try setting the shell ruby by: `rbenv shell 2.3.1`

Comment: Have you run `rbenv init` as well? It could be that rbenv is not properly integrated into your shell. https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#how-rbenv-hooks-into-your-shell

Comment: this might be a silly question, but have you got .ruby-version in your project's top level directory? And that it points to the correct ruby version?

Comment: I solved the issue by running 'rbenv local 2.3.1'