# Gem install command doesn't work

Tags: rubygems

I'm now using macbook terminal to study rails. 
I'm trying to install ruby on rails so I got homebrew and rbenv. 
And I entered "gem install rails" to get rails but he said

> "ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)     cannot load such file
>   -- openssl ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
>       undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass"

I have no idea with this error because i usually use windows.. 
I thought that gem installed uncompletely so i tried to reinstall gem, 
but i couldn't even find how to reinstall this. 
plz help me..

Comment: Please run the following and update your question with the results: **Ruby Version:** `ruby -v`; **Rubygems version:** `gem --version`;

Comment: ruby -v : ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [x86_64-darwin14.0.0] // gem --version : 2.0.14.1 this is my result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of Ruby is **`2.4.0`**, and
the latest version of Rubygems, is **`2.6.11`**

While its not necessary that you need to use the latest version of Ruby itself,
(Note: Rails 4.x is compatible with your version, but Rails 5.x isn't), updating the Rubygems version should help. To update Rubygems version simply run

```
$ gem update --system
```

---

--- UPDATE: ---

If that doesn't work, you can install the latest version of Rubygems manually at https://rubygems.org/pages/download

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but the result is similar with that,, ERROR : Loading command : update (LoadError) // I think there is some problem with my gem..

Comment: updated answer with a link to manually download latest version of Rubygems.

Comment: wow thanks. i think gem is correctly reinstalled but another problem arose. After reinstall gem, i retried "gem install rails" but he said "Error installing rails : activesupport requires ruby versions >= 2.2.2." So I tried to update my ruby by rbenv, and the command "rbenv version" results is "2.3.3 (set by /usr/local/bin/.ruby-version)". But when i tried "ruby -v", the result is "ruby 2.0.0p648 ~~~~~". And of course "gem install rails" result is same with first try. I don't know what's wrong with this.

Comment: after you update ruby version via `rbenv`, you need to make it the default version. Run **`$ rbenv local 2.3.3`** for the current user account and if you have top level access, **`$ rbenv global 2.3.3`** to make it the default for all users on the system.

Comment: I already did "rbenv global 2.3.3" and "rbenv local 2.3.3". And the result of both of "rbenv global" and "rbenv local" are "2.3.3". But result of "ruby -v" is "2.0.0."

Comment: refer [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version) for possible solutions to current problem.

Comment: Thanks!! Finally I installed rails in my mac. As I have a poor ability of english, I can't express my appreciation more than this. Thank you very much!