# rbenv working but ruby version not changing

Tags: ruby, macos-sierra, rbenv

```
❯ rbenv version
system (set by /Users/eric.nguyen/.rbenv/version)
                                                                                                                                                             
❯ rbenv local 2.4.2
                                                                                                                                                           

❯ gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
                                                                                                                                                           
❯ rbenv global 2.4.2
                                                                                                                                                           
❯ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
                                                                                                                                                           
❯ rbenv version
2.4.2 (set by /Users/eric.nguyen/.ruby-version)
                                                                                                                                                           
❯ gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
                                                                                                                                                           
❯ gem -v
2.0.14.1
```

Ruby version is is still 2.0.0p648

I'm on macOS Sierra 10.12.6.
I've done everything mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version)

I've done:

1. `rbenv rehash`
2. put `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` in my .zshrc and `source ~/.zshrc`
3. put `$HOME/.rbenv/shims` into $PATH (/Users/eric.nguyen/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/eric.nguyen/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/eric.nguyen/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/eric.nguyen/.rbenv/shims)

But it still doesn't change ruby version.

Comment: Make sure you have `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` in your `.bash_profile` AND you exit and open a new terminal window (or `source .bash_profile` in any open windows)

Comment: @Joe I already have that

Comment: have you issued a 'rbenv rehash' ?

Comment: what's the output for `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restarting my computer resolve the issue.

```
❯ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin16]


❯ gem -v
2.6.13
```

Answer (score 2):

You always need to run `rbenv rehash` after you install a new ruby version using rbenv and also when you install a gem that has a command line options