# I upgraded Ruby to version 2.5.0 and when i run ruby -v it still shows an older version

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I upgraded ruby from 2.2.3 using rbenv following these instructions

```
$ brew update
$ brew install ruby-build
$ brew install rbenv
$ rbenv install 2.5.0
$ rbenv global 2.5.0
$ rbenv local 2.5.0
```

i restarted my terminal and my computer but when i run

```
ruby -v
```

it shows that i have

```
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

when i run rbenv version

```
  system
  2.4.0
  2.5.0 (set by /Users/****/.ruby-version)
```

it doesn't even show this version, i'm stuck on what i have to do to change this to point to the correct version.

When i run

```
$echo $PATH
```

it shows

```
-bash: /usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:/Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin:/Users/****/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/Users/****/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/****/.rvm/bin: No such file or directory
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version

Comment: `/Users/****/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/` -- There's the red flag. You're using `rbenv` and `rvm` at the same time. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your path, it looks like you are using `rvm`. I think `rvm` and `rbenv` should not be both active on the same system. If you are going to use `rbenv` I suggest you disable `rvm`. You don't need to delete the `.rvm` directory containing `rvm`'s rubies, gems, etc., you just need to stop the `rvm` shell code from being loaded when the terminal window starts up. To do this, disable or remove the rvm-related code in your `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.zshrc`, etc., and use a new terminal window that starts up after that removal.

I suspect the 2.2.3 version of Ruby is the `system` you see in the list. If you do a `which ruby`, you can see where it's located, and that will be a clue; if it's `/usr/bin/ruby`, then it's the system Ruby.

As an aside, you can get a list of directories in the PATH one to a line by using this command:

```
echo $PATH | tr : \\n
```

This would be much easier to follow than the long line containing all the directories.

Comment: Thank you! i just figured this out i was about to post the answer, seems like i had originally installed it via RVM like you said and i tried upgrading it using rbenv so it was conflicting, i ended up deleting rvm and changing my bash_profile like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version suggested and it work