# Ruby version is not changing

Tags: ruby, installation

I'm a beginner trying to setup ruby and start learning. I feel stuck just on figuring out whether my PC is using the latest ruby version..
when I do this:

```
➜  ~ rbenv global 2.6.5                  
➜  ~ ruby -v           
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]
➜  ~ export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
➜  ~ env | grep PATH                     
PATH=/Users/Prodigy/.rbenv/bin:/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin:/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:./bin:./node_modules/.bin:/Users/Prodigy/.rbenv/shims:/Users/Prodigy/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/bin
GEM_PATH=/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3:/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global
➜  ~ whereis ruby                        
/usr/bin/ruby
➜  ~ which ruby                          
/Users/Prodigy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby
➜  ~ rbenv versions                      
  system
  2.5.3
* 2.6.5 (set by /Users/Prodigy/.ruby-version)
```

I restarted my terminal and my laptop. I also tried to use the tips mentioned here ([rbenv not changing ruby version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version)) but I don't think it's relevant to my issue. I would really appreciate your help thanks!

Comment: rbenv global 2.6.5                  
source ~/.bashrc

Comment: Copy pasted that but no effect...
```
➜  ~ rbenv global 2.6.5 source ~/.bashrc
➜  ~ ruby -v                            
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

Answer (score 0):

NVM, I fixed it after following the Step 3.1: Install rbenv mentioned here:

https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/web-development-101/lessons/installing-ruby?ref=lnav

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ rbenv rehash
$ rehash
```