# docker-compose picks the wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby, docker-compose, rbenv

When running docker-compose, it seems to pick the wrong ruby program.
Using rbenv I have installed version 2.6.2
But there is also a version under /usr/bin that is at 2.6.3. I can't delete that version, also not as sudo.
I have already uninstalled rbenv and re-installed it.

The strange thing is this:

```
MBP-Andre:biblestudy_platform andreheijstek$ which ruby
/Users/andreheijstek/.rbenv/shims/ruby
MBP-Andre:biblestudy_platform andreheijstek$ whereis ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

When I run docker-compose, it seems to pick the usr/bin/ruby, which is the wrong one!

I've tried to take all the advise under [rbenv not changing ruby version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version?) but nothing helps.
Any ideas?

Maybe some more background to clarify the situation.
I have followed this advise to dockerise my existing rails app.
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/ruby-on-whales-docker-for-ruby-rails-development

Here, the docker-compose wil create the docker.
My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

x-app: &app
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./.dockerdev/Dockerfile
    args:
      RUBY_VERSION: '2.6.2'
      PG_MAJOR: '11'
      NODE_MAJOR: '11'
      YARN_VERSION: '1.13.0'
      BUNDLER_VERSION: '2.0.2'
  environment: &env
    NODE_ENV: development
    RAILS_ENV: ${RAILS_ENV:-development}
  image: example-dev:1.0.0
  tmpfs:
    - /tmp

x-backend: &backend
  <<: *app
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
  volumes:
    - .:/app:cached
    - rails_cache:/app/tmp/cache
    - bundle:/bundle
    - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    - packs:/app/public/packs
    - .dockerdev/.psqlrc:/root/.psqlrc:ro
  environment:
    <<: *env
    REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/
    DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432
    BOOTSNAP_CACHE_DIR: /bundle/bootsnap
    WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST: webpacker
    WEB_CONCURRENCY: 1
    HISTFILE: /app/log/.bash_history
    PSQL_HISTFILE: /app/log/.psql_history
    EDITOR: vi
  depends_on:
    - postgres
    - redis

services:
  runner:
    <<: *backend
    command: /bin/bash
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
      - '3002:3002'

  rails:
    <<: *backend
    command: bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'

  sidekiq:
    <<: *backend
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml

  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.1
    volumes:
      - .dockerdev/.psqlrc:/root/.psqlrc:ro
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./log:/root/log:cached
    environment:
      PSQL_HISTFILE: /root/log/.psql_history
    ports:
      - 5432

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2-alpine
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
    ports:
      - 6379

  webpacker:
    <<: *app
    command: ./bin/webpack-dev-server
    ports:
      - '3035:3035'
    volumes:
      - .:/app:cached
      - bundle:/bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - packs:/app/public/packs
    environment:
      <<: *env
      WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST: 0.0.0.0

volumes:
  postgres:
  redis:
  bundle:
  node_modules:
  rails_cache:
  packs:
```

And my Dockerfile

```
# Taken from: https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/ruby-on-whales-docker-for-ruby-rails-development

ARG RUBY_VERSION
FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION

RUN echo RUBY_VERSION

ARG PG_MAJOR
ARG NODE_MAJOR
ARG BUNDLER_VERSION
ARG YARN_VERSION

# Add PostgreSQL to sources list
RUN curl -sSL https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ stretch-pgdg main' $PG_MAJOR > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

# Add NodeJS to sources list
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_MAJOR.x | bash -

# Add Yarn to the sources list
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb http://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

# Install dependencies
COPY .dockerdev/Aptfile /tmp/Aptfile
RUN apt-get update -qq && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq dist-upgrade && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    postgresql-client-$PG_MAJOR \
    nodejs \
    yarn=$YARN_VERSION-1 \
    $(cat /tmp/Aptfile | xargs) && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* && \
    truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log

# Configure bundler and PATH
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
  GEM_HOME=/bundle \
  BUNDLE_JOBS=4 \
  BUNDLE_RETRY=3
ENV BUNDLE_PATH $GEM_HOME
ENV BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=$BUNDLE_PATH \
  BUNDLE_BIN=$BUNDLE_PATH/bin
ENV PATH /app/bin:$BUNDLE_BIN:$PATH

# Upgrade RubyGems and install required Bundler version
RUN gem update --system && \
    gem install bundler:$BUNDLER_VERSION

# Create a directory for the app code
RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app
```

When I try to create everything, this happens:

```
MBP-Andre:biblestudy_platform andreheijstek$ docker-compose up rails
biblestudy_platform_postgres_1 is up-to-date
biblestudy_platform_redis_1 is up-to-date
Starting biblestudy_platform_rails_1 ... done
Attaching to biblestudy_platform_rails_1
rails_1      | Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.2
biblestudy_platform_rails_1 exited with code 18
```

Comment: Are those commands from within your container?

Comment: There's probably a .ruby-version file in the root of your project (it's a hidden file), rbenv will check for this and use the version listed there if it's installed

Comment: The commands are outside the container. The .ruby-version is 2.6.2, which is what I want

Comment: As the other person answering stated - when you're running the docker container it doesn't have access to anything stored outside of it - you need to setup a docker container that comes with ruby installed

Comment: Check out https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby

Comment: @andreheijstek I have the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You seems to misunderstood the concept of docker container. It should be standalone and use it's own environment, not anything outside of it or 
 from your rbenv.
I would suggest to build your app with [ruby docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/pull/5542). Start with Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.2
...
```

Depend on what you want, if you want light weight, use slim or alpine,... You don't need rbenv for this.

Comment: The commands are outside my container. The problem is in building the container, where the wrong version is used.
    MBP-Andre:biblestudy_platform andreheijstek$ docker-compose up rails
    biblestudy_platform_postgres_1 is up-to-date
    biblestudy_platform_redis_1 is up-to-date.   
    Starting biblestudy_platform_rails_1 ... done
Attaching to biblestudy_platform_rails_1
rails_1      | Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.2
biblestudy_platform_rails_1 exited with code 18

Comment: Have you tried my solution? as I said as well as Mark's comment, a docker container should not use anything outside of it @andreheijstek

Comment: The FROM ruby:2.6.2 is already in my Dockerfile. It is there as FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION (and I just tried to explicitly state 2.6.2 as well), But that doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4260
I thinks add that an `rbenv rehash` solved this issue

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. 

`$ rbenv rehash
$ which ruby
/Users/andreheijstek/.rbenv/shims/ruby
$ whereis ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
$ docker-compose up rails
biblestudy_platform_postgres_1 is up-to-date
biblestudy_platform_redis_1 is up-to-date
Starting biblestudy_platform_rails_1 ... done
Attaching to biblestudy_platform_rails_1
rails_1      | Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.2
biblestudy_platform_rails_1 exited with code 18`