# How do I use rbenv (specifically adding to bash_profile)?

Tags: ruby

When I run `rbenv init` I get the following message ...

[image]

I opened the .bash_profile file in Textedit and I am not sure where exactly I am supposed to add the file. Below is my .bash_profile file. Where am I supposed to add the command?

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm 

bash_completion

##
# Your previous /Users/(name)/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/(name)/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2019-10-27_at_02:02:44
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2019-10-27_at_02:02:44: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext. [Images of plaintext are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). You have access to the plaintext; please copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rbenv not changing ruby version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version)

Answer (score 0):

"Append" means "add to the end" ([in both English and in many programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Append)).

Add that snippet to the bottom of your `.bash_profile`.