# bundler using system ruby version instead of downloaded

Tags: ruby, bundle, bundler, rbenv

This is a basic question, but I've been banging my head against a wall trying to fix this and I'm stuck.

I'm cloning a rails project.

When I run `bundle install` I get:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.5
```

so I tried to make sure that I'm using the right version using `rbenv versions`. I get:

```
  system
* 2.5.5 (set by /Users/Mahmoud/dev-reps/non-docker/backend/.ruby-version)
```

which means that rbenv is using the correct version. Now I run `which bundle`:

```
/usr/local/bin/bundle
```

which means that bundler is using the system version.

As for `which -a bundle` gives:

```
/usr/local/bin/bundle
/usr/bin/bundle
```

Also when I run `which ruby` or `which -a ruby`, I get:

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Something I tried though, points to light at the end of the tunnel. When [I try based on this post] this[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version):

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

and rerun bundle install, it works. The problem though, the change isn't persistent. I close shell and retry, and I'm right where I started

I've uninstalled and re-installed bundler multiple times after rehashing, etc. but I'm still seeing that rbenv isn't "in control". It tells me one version is in use, but the fact is that the system version is being used.

**Update**

Based on one of the comments, I uninstalled rbenv and redownloaded. Now after `rbenv rehash` I get the following when I type `which ruby`:

```
/Users/Mahmoud/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

which is perfect. `which bundle` however gives:

```
/usr/local/bin/bundle
```

so the problem persists. I also tried `gem install bundler` but still when I type `bundle install` I'm getting the same problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens when you run the commant which ruby?

Comment: Added it bro :D

Comment: Can you check your `.bash_profile` if it contains the `.rbenv` path? Otherwise you need to go back to install `rbenv` correctly.

Comment: which ruby should point to your rbenv path

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek my .bash_profile is empty :(

Comment: any ideas how can I fix this? @OuttaSpaceTime

Comment: what is the output of `which -a ruby` and `which -a bundle` ?

Comment: I would try to go through complete reinstallation of rbenv

Comment: @OuttaSpaceTime did this, and now `which ruby` points to rbenv. `which bundle` though is problematic. Can you check the question above, i've edited

Comment: Working now..I'll add an answer specifying all the steps that I went through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okkk, so after hours and with help from comments here and the answer given above I was able to get it to work.

The problem it seemed was that rbenv was not properly setup. To fix it, it's either to uninstall and install again. Did this through:

1. `brew remove rbenv`
2. `rm -rf ~/.rbenv`
3. Removed a line containing rbenv from `~/.zshrc`

This removed rbenv. I then reinstalled using:

1. `brew install rbenv`
2. Then initialized using `rbenv init`. This effectively fixes the problem of rbenv. Now after restarting terminal, whenever I ran `which ruby`, I'd get:

`/Users/Mahmoud/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

meaning in short that the system now relies on rbenv for its ruby version management instead of looking in the system. This is crucial for the working of rbenv, and in essence this is it's whole "raison d'etre"; to take the job of managing ruby on your pc away from your pc.

After this step I ran `gem install bundler`. Following this step when I run `which bundle` it would give:

```
/Users/Mahmoud/.rbenv/shims/bundle
```

so everything is in place and working fine

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have `rbenv` set up in your shell. You can find the instructions on how to do this in the rbenv docs [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#how-rbenv-hooks-into-your-shell).

Comment: for some weird reason rbenv init - does not fix anything