# Error running '__rvm_make install' on macOS Monterey

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, rvm

I am trying to install ruby 2.7.0 version on mac(12.2.1) using rvm but getting below error, and tried all the solution possible on github nothing seems to work. Even tried using rbenv but same error. Please help, thank you in advance.

```
rashmi.b@xxxx Documents % rvm install 2.7.0     
ruby-2.7.0 - #removing src/ruby-2.7.0 - please wait
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/12.2/x86_64/ruby-2.7.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/rashmi.b/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.7.0 - #downloading ruby-2.7.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.7.0 - #extracting ruby-2.7.0 to /Users/rashmi.b/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.0 - please wait
ruby-2.7.0 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-2.7.0 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-2.7.0 - #compiling - please wait
ruby-2.7.0 - #installing - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make install',
please read /Users/rashmi.b/.rvm/log/1647236002_ruby-2.7.0/install.log
There has been an error while running make install. Halting the installation.
```

/Users/rashmi.b/.rvm/log/1647236002_ruby-2.7.0/install.log =>

```
generating x86_64-darwin21-fake.rb
x86_64-darwin21-fake.rb updated
        BASERUBY = /usr/bin/ruby --disable=gems
        CC = gcc
        LD = ld
        LDSHARED = gcc -dynamiclib
        CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -std=gnu99  -fno-common -pipe
        XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT -DCANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin21 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/12.1.0
        CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT
        DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -install_name /Users/rashmi.b/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib -compatibility_version 2.7 -current_version 2.7.0  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation
        SOLIBS = -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lobjc
        LANG =
        LC_ALL =
        LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
        MFLAGS =
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
generating enc.mk
making srcs under enc
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `srcs'.
generating transdb.h
transdb.h unchanged
generating makefiles ext/configure-ext.mk
ext/configure-ext.mk updated
generating makefile exts.mk
exts.mk unchanged
./revision.h unchanged
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `note'.
making enc
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `enc'.
making trans
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `./enc/trans'.
making encs
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `encs'.
./miniruby -I./lib -I. -I.ext/common  ./tool/runruby.rb --extout=.ext  -- --disable-gems -r./x86_64-darwin21-fake ./tool/rbinstall.rb --make="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make" --dest-dir="" --extout=".ext" --mflags="" --make-flags="" --data-mode=0644 --prog-mode=0755 --installed-list .installed.list --mantype="doc" --exclude=doc
make: *** [do-install-nodoc] Killed: 9
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

Openssl version - 3.0.1 14

Comment: Have you followed the hint in the error message: "please read /Users/rashmi.b/.rvm/log/1647236002_ruby-2.7.0/install.log" What was in there? Please edit your question and add the contents of the log file.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the log contents.

Answer (score 4):

If any one face problem with OSX Montrerey and installing Ruby 2.7.0 use the following instead of wasting so much trying:

- `brew install ruby-build`
- `brew install rbenv`
- `CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rbenv install 2.7.0`
- `rbenv global 2.7.0`
- `rbenv local --unset`
- `rbenv init -`
- `echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

source of second half of solution is here to select the version you just installed by the OS
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39238995/3086197

replace 2.7.0 with the version you need

Comment: This worked for me!. Use ~/.zshrc if you are not using bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something forcefully killed your compilation process. Unfortunately, it's not clear what external process that was, but it might be some virus scanner or other security software on your mac.

In any case, please be aware that no released Ruby supports OpenSSL 3.0 yet. You have to use OpenSSL 1.1.1 in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by running `rvm install 2.7.3 -j 1`

[Error running '__rvm_make -j16'](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5146#issuecomment-990936407)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install ruby 3.2.1.
There was such error: `Error running '__rvm_make -j10'`
Helped to swap to a lower thread count.
Create file `~/.rvmrc`
Add this:

```
rvm_make_flags=( -j1 )
```