# `auth_data=': couldn't set additional authenticated data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rubygems

I am new on RoR and created a new project with all configurations of ruby and rails.

I have

- mac version 12.4 Monterey
- rails 6.0.5
- ruby 2.7.2
- postgresql

I configured these using rbnev from this tutorial https://gorails.com/setup/osx/12-monterey  and https://collectionbuilder.github.io/cb-docs/docs/software/ruby_mac/

I created new app using `rails new myapp -d postgresql`. It's showing this error while building the project:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.5/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:173:in `auth_data=': couldn't set additional authenticated data (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.5/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:173:in `_encrypt'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.5/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:151:in `encrypt_and_sign'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.5/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:76:in `encrypt'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.5/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:50:in `write'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.5/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:29:in `write'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.5/lib/rails/generators/rails/credentials/credentials_generator.rb:30:in `add_credentials_file_silently'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.5/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:177:in `credentials'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.5/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:155:in `build'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.5/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:332:in `create_credentials'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `invoke_all'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.5/lib/rails/commands/application/application_command.rb:26:in `perform'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.5/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.5/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.5/lib/rails/cli.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.5/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/rails:22:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try to reinstall rails gem in your device. that may help you and let me know what happend...

Comment: i have rails 6.0.5 but when i try to uninstall the rails by using "gem uninstall rails" it's showing: Gem 'rails' is not installed

Comment: @AbrarJahin it's showing me the rails version but don't have any local gems rails in my system

Comment: Did you tried to run `gem install rails` command again after getting the `Gem 'rails' is not installed`

Comment: yes i tried this command but it gives me this --> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.

Answer (score 0):

According to your issues on MAC device for ROR, You might be facing the issues because of versioning system and rbnev, and I got an article over the internet that described the same issue with some solutions.

[Maybe this article will help you to fix that problem](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/rails-is-not-currently-installed-on-this-system/)

If you can fix the issue from the article then let me know here too.

Comment: Thank you for your response but i checked this article before but it's not working for me

Comment: it resolved with the help of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version